# How do I format a date with Dart?

Tags: dart

I have an instance of `DateTime` and I would like to format that to a String. How do I do that? I want to turn the date into a string, something like "2013-04-20".

Answer (score 760, accepted):

You can use the [`intl`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) package ([installer](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install)) to format dates.

For `en_US` formats, it's quite simple:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted); // something like 2013-04-20
}
```

There are many options for formatting. From the docs:

```
ICU Name                   Skeleton
--------                   --------
DAY                          d
ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
WEEKDAY                      EEEE
ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
NUM_MONTH                    M
NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
MONTH                        MMMM
MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
QUARTER                      QQQQ
YEAR                         y
YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
HOUR24                       H
HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
HOUR                         j
HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
HOUR_MINUTE_GENERIC_TZ       jmv
HOUR_MINUTE_TZ               jmz
HOUR_GENERIC_TZ              jv
HOUR_TZ                      jz
MINUTE                       m
MINUTE_SECOND                ms
SECOND                       s
```

For non-`en_US` dates, you need to explicitly load in the locale. See the [`DateFormat` docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for more info. The [`date_symbol_data_local.dart`](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/date_symbol_data_local.dart) contains all of the formats for each country/language, if you would like a more in-depth look.

Comment: Is intl broken? Uncaught Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'E:\dart\ws\web\packages\intl\intl.dart' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Is there any way to add milliseconds to the format?

Comment: requires in pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
intl: ^0.15.7

Comment: how can we fetch only month eg. 1 for january, 2 for february... ? i have tried DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now()); but does not work in flutter. Please share your suggestion.

Comment: @Kaspi try 'S' for fractional second

Comment: how to get 2020-10-22 15:30:45 (Y-m-d H:i:s) format ?

Comment: Got the solution for database. final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss');
    final String formatted = formatter.format(now);

Comment: @Kamlesh if You want to get only the month number, You can do `DateTime.now().month` :)

Comment: I wish AndroidStudio would learn to auto-import `'package:intl/intl.dart';`... it's almost 2021, we're going to colonize Mars soon

Comment: 2021-12-07T22:29:42.843+00:00 What about this format? I've tried to parse it but it doesnt work

Comment: ICU format names are also available [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax) with more examples.

Comment: From when did en-US format became 'yyyy-MM-dd'? Isn't it 'MM-dd-yyyy'?!

Answer (score 70):

This will work too:

```dart
DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
String dateSlug ="${today.year.toString()}-${today.month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}-${today.day.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}";
print(dateSlug);
```

Comment: This is not advisable because it is not localized in a users locale.

Comment: @DustinB Are you sure? It seems to be localized in my case, but if it isn't, then just convert it. `DateTime.toLocal()` should do the trick.

Comment: Well, it is doing string concatenation in the format of YEAR-MM-DD. That may match your current locale, but definitely not everyones. In US, it is more likely to use MM/DD/YYYY for example.

Comment: @EzPizza toLocal() is a timezone conversation not an international conversion.

Comment: @RalphShillington Oops, I actually thought the question was about timezones. Yeah this solution only works for a specific locale then.

Answer (score 51):

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  intl:
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; // for date format
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart'; // for other locales

void main() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  print(DateFormat().format(now)); // This will return date using the default locale
  print(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').format(now));
  print(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(now)); // print long date 
  print(DateFormat.yMd().format(now)); // print short date 
  print(DateFormat.jms().format(now)); // print time 

  initializeDateFormatting('es'); // This will initialize Spanish locale
  print(DateFormat.yMMMMd('es').format(now)); // print long date in Spanish format
  print(DateFormat.yMd('es').format(now)); // print short date in Spanish format
  print(DateFormat.jms('es').format(now)); // print time in Spanish format
}
```

Result:

```
May 31, 2020 5:41:42 PM
2020-05-31 05:41:42
May 31, 2020
5/31/2020
5:41:42 PM
31 de mayo de 2020
31/5/2020
17:41:42
```

Comment: This is the best solution because be adapt to locale

Answer (score 41):

You can also specify the date format like stated earlier: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
String formatDate(DateTime date) => new DateFormat("MMMM d").format(date);
```

Produces: `March 4`

Answer (score 36):

If someone wants to convert a date in string format to some other string format first use DateTime.parse("2019-09-30") then pass it to DateFormat("date pattern").format() like

```
dateFormate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.parse("2019-09-30"));
```

**Reference:** [Dart - How to change format of simple date string which is in yyyy-MM-dd to dd-MM-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040606/dart-how-to-change-format-of-simple-date-string-which-is-in-yyyy-mm-dd-to-dd-m#answer-58042809)

Comment: your code uses `DateFormat` but your text says `DateTime.format()`

Comment: Oops! a blunder. Changed :)

Comment: This question is specifically about converting a `DateTime` to a `String` (formatting).  If you want to convert a `String` to a `DateTime` (parsing), then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/.

Answer (score 23):

You can use this method as well, if you don't want to add another library

```
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
  String YYYY_MM_DD = dateTime.toIso8601String().split('T').first;
  print(YYYY_MM_DD); //2020-11-23
```

Answer (score 21):

This give you the date like in a social network : ["today","yesterday","dayoftheweek",etc..]

```
void main() {
      DateTime now = new DateTime(2018,6,26);
      print(date(now));
    }
    
    String date(DateTime tm) {
      DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
      Duration oneDay = new Duration(days: 1);
      Duration twoDay = new Duration(days: 2);
      Duration oneWeek = new Duration(days: 7);
      String month;
      switch (tm.month) {
        case 1:
          month = "january";
          break;
        case 2:
          month = "february";
          break;
        case 3:
          month = "march";
          break;
        case 4:
          month = "april";
          break;
        case 5:
          month = "may";
          break;
        case 6:
          month = "june";
          break;
        case 7:
          month = "july";
          break;
        case 8:
          month = "august";
          break;
        case 9:
          month = "september";
          break;
        case 10:
          month = "october";
          break;
        case 11:
          month = "november";
          break;
        case 12:
          month = "december";
          break;
      }
    
      Duration difference = today.difference(tm);
    
      if (difference.compareTo(oneDay) < 1) {
        return "today";
      } else if (difference.compareTo(twoDay) < 1) {
        return "yesterday";
      } else if (difference.compareTo(oneWeek) < 1) {
        switch (tm.weekday) {
          case 1:
            return "monday";
          case 2:
            return "tuesday";
          case 3:
            return "wednesday";
          case 4:
            return "thursday";
          case 5:
            return "friday";
          case 6:
            return "saturday";
          case 7:
            return "sunday";
        }
      } else if (tm.year == today.year) {
        return '${tm.day} $month';
      } else {
        return '${tm.day} $month ${tm.year}';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Very useful - thank you. Add this additional line at top of method if you are passing dates which have a time, otherwise 'yesterday' may not work:
tm = DateTime(tm.year, tm.month, tm.day);

Comment: Instead of the switch statement, wouldnt it be better to use @RodyDavis answer of using  import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
String formatDate(DateTime date) => new DateFormat("MMMM").format(date);

that will also set it up for anyone who then wants it to display in Spanish, Arabic etc..
those additional steps can be found in 
[this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264072/changing-date-formatters-locale)

Comment: and using DateFormat("EEEE") for the days

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to format dates in flutter.

```
void main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat format = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = format.format(now);
  // 2021-03-02
}
```

or you can use [date_format](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format) package to format dates in flutter.

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

final formattedStr = formatDate(DateTime.now(), [dd, '-', mm, '-', yyyy]);

//02-03-2021
```

Answer (score 19):

Another way, using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

**Create an extension of DateTime:**

**date_time_extension.dart**

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  String format([String pattern = 'dd/MM/yyyy', String? locale]) {
    if (locale != null && locale.isNotEmpty) {
      initializeDateFormatting(locale);
    }
    return DateFormat(pattern, locale).format(this);
  }
}
```

Import this file where you are going to use DateTime type, and you can use it like this:

```
DateTime.now().format();

DateTime.now().format('MM/yyyy');

DateTime.now().format('MM/yyyy', 'es');
```

Answer (score 13):

There is a package date_format

```
dependencies:
    date_format:
```

code

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

final formattedStr = formatDate(
    yourDateTime, [dd, '.', mm, '.', yy, ' ', HH, ':', nn]);

// output example "29.03.19 07:00"
```

Pay attention: minutes are **nn**

[link to the package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/date_format#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score 11):

```
main() {
  final String pattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
  final String formatted = DateFormat(pattern).format(DateTime.now());
  print(formatted);
}
```

Changing `yyyy-MM-dd` string you can change your date format. I made app for play with this pattern string.

You can experiment format string in my app It made with flutter.
https://biplobsd.github.io/EpochConverterApp

[Here you can see how can I edit the pattern and this effect showing on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcBWm.gif)

Answer (score 7):

Set your project [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) pakage

```
dateTimeFormet (date){
   //MM-dd-yyyy
   //yyyy-MM-dd 
   return DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(date);// you can set your formet
}

void main (){
  var date = 01-11-2022 00 : 00
  var _datetime = dateTimeFormet(date);
  print(_dateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
/// Get date as a string for display.
String getFormattedDate(String date) {
  /// Convert into local date format.
  var localDate = DateTime.parse(date).toLocal();

  /// inputFormat - format getting from api or other func.
  /// e.g If 2021-05-27 9:34:12.781341 then format must be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
  /// If 27/05/2021 9:34:12.781341 then format must be dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
  var inputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
  var inputDate = inputFormat.parse(localDate.toString());

  /// outputFormat - convert into format you want to show.
  var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
  var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);

  return outputDate.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the case you want to combine several date format into one, this is how we can do using `intl`.

```
DateFormat('yMMMd').addPattern(DateFormat.HOUR24_MINUTE).format(yourDateTime))
```

Answer (score 4):

**NO DEPENDENCY METHOD [FOR DISPLAYING DATE AS FORMATTED STRING]**

If you want to show your DateTime value as a day/month/year or any other format you like, string interpolation can be handy :

```
"${_date.day} / ${_date.month} / ${_date.year}"
```

sample output :

> 23 / 4 / 1920

I don't want to use any additional library, so i went this way.

Answer (score 3):

handling yearly quarters, from string to DateTime, I didn't find proper solution so made this:

```
    List<String> dateAsList = 'Q1 2001'.split(' ');
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    String quarter = dateAsList[0];
    int year = int.parse(dateAsList[1]);
    switch(quarter) {
      case "Q1": dateTime = DateTime(year, 1);
      break;
      case "Q2": dateTime = DateTime(year, 4);
      break;
      case "Q3": dateTime = DateTime(year, 7);
      break;
      case "Q4": dateTime = DateTime(year, 10);
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a nice user-friendly string that includes both the date and the time, you can use this:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  final DateTime someDateTime = DateTime(2017, 9, 7, 17, 30);
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jms();
  final String formatted = formatter.format(someDateTime);
  print(formatted); // Sep 7, 2017 5:30:00 PM (in the US)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  var formattedDate = new DateTime.Format('yyyy-MM-dd').DateTime.now();
  print(formattedDate); // something like 2020-04-16
}
```

For more details can refer [DateFormat Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
String formatDate(String date) {
    return date.substring(0, 10).split('-').reversed.join().replaceAll('-', '/');
    
  }
```

From format "yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s"

Answer (score 0):

```
 String dateConverter(String date) {
    // Input date Format
    final format = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    DateTime gettingDate = format.parse(date);
    final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    // Output Date Format
    final String formatted = formatter.format(gettingDate);
    return date;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way:

```
new DateFormat("dd-MM-y").format(YOUR_DATETIME_HERE)
```

Comment: Previous answers seem to cover this already.

Answer (score 0):

Use "H:mm" to see full minutes like 13:08 not 13:8

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29850082)

Answer (score 0):

Since the flutter usual Datetime library doesn't know the locale for Germany - neither de, nor DE, nor de_DE, nor de-DE or any other combinations, for example if you want to have the name of the month or the name of the day written in human readable string, I suggest you to use the following code.

install pub `flutter pub add date_format`

```
String formattedDate = formatDate(DateTime(year, month, day),[dd,'. ', MM, ' ', yyyy], locale: GermanDateLocale());
```

Answer (score -2):

Current Day:

```
DateTime.now().day, //something like 26
```

---

Current Month:

```
DateTime.now().month, //something like 4
```

---

Current Year:

```
DateTime.now().year, //something like 2022
```

---

Current Houre:

```
DateTime.now().hour, //something like 12
```

---

Current Minute:

```
DateTime.now().minute, //something like 13
```

---

Current Second:

```
DateTime.now().second, //something like 44
```