# How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?

Tags: datetime, dart

Say I have a string

```
"1974-03-20 00:00:00.000"
```

It is created using `DateTime.now()`,
how do I convert the string back to a `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

`DateTime` has  a `parse` method

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse('1974-03-20 00:00:00.000');
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: not support for "2019-02-14T16:27:30.1519239+03:30" because that regex just support 6 digit for milisecond not 7

Comment: That's a known limitation.

Comment: that datetime was generated from c# server and flutter client could not deserialize it

Comment: hey guys, 

I have a date in this format "2019-07-31T11:25:46.2265012Z" from a .Net server - has anyone managed to find a solution to convert this string to date?

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.parse(...)` as shown above?

Comment: Yes, I get the following error : FormatException: Invalid date format

here is the date as a string : 2019-08-01T08:06:10.7790549Z

Comment: Can you please try with `T` replaced by ` ` (space) if you get the same error?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes still get the same error - here is what I tried DateTime.parse("2019-07-31 11:25:46.2265012Z");

Error: "Invalid date format2019-07-31 11:25:46.2265012Z"

Comment: I just tried it in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/. You can leave the `T`, but you have to remove one digit from the seconds fractions (the last digit before `Z`).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - cheers pal, I will try to find a string manipulation method to remove 2nd last character of my date string.

Comment: @user3057745 Yup, I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 100):

There seem to be a *lot* of questions about parsing timestamp strings into `DateTime`.  I will try to give a more general answer so that future questions can be directed here.

- **Your timestamp is in an ISO format.**  Examples: `1999-04-23`, `1999-04-23 13:45:56Z`, `19990423T134556.789`.  In this case, you can use `DateTime.parse` or `DateTime.tryParse`. (See [the `DateTime.parse` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) for the precise set of allowed inputs.)
- **Your timestamp is in a [standard HTTP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1).** Examples: `Fri, 23 Apr 1999 13:45:56 GMT`, `Friday, 23-Apr-99 13:45:56 GMT`, `Fri Apr 23 13:45:56 1999`. In this case, you can use `dart:io`'s [`HttpDate.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpDate/parse.html) function.
- **Your timestamp is in some local format.**  Examples: `23/4/1999`, `4/23/99`, `April 23, 1999`.  You can use [`package:intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)'s [`DateFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class and provide a *pattern* specifying how to parse the string:

  ```dart
  import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

  ...

  var dmyString = '23/4/1999';
  var dateTime1 = DateFormat('d/M/y').parse(dmyString);

  var mdyString = '04/23/99'; 
  var dateTime2 = DateFormat('MM/dd/yy').parse(mdyString);

  var mdyFullString = 'April 23, 1999';
  var dateTime3 = DateFormat('MMMM d, y', 'en_US').parse(mdyFullString));
  ```

  See [the `DateFormat` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for more information about the pattern syntax.

  **`DateFormat` limitations:**

  - [`DateFormat` cannot parse dates that lack explicit field separators](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/210).  For such cases, you can use `FixedDateTimeFormatter` (see below).
  - Prior to version 0.17.0 of `package:intl`, [`yy` did not follow the -80/+20 rule](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/123) that the documentation describes for inferring the century, so if you use a 2-digit year, you might need to adjust the century afterward.
  - As of writing, [`DateFormat` does not support time zones](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/19).  If you need to deal with time zones, [you will need to handle them separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64145309/).
- **Your timestamp is in a fixed, known, numeric format.** Examples: `19990423`, `04-23-1999`.  You can use [`package:convert`](https://pub.dev/packages/convert)'s [`FixedDateTimeFormatter`](https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/FixedDateTimeFormatter-class.html) and provide a pattern specifying how to parse the string:

  ```dart
  import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

  ...

  var dateString = '19990423';
  var dateTime = FixedDateTimeFormatter ('YYYYMMDD').decode(dateString);
  ```

  (Note that `FixedDateTimeFormatter` and `DateFormat` use different patterns.)

  As a **last resort**, you always use regular expressions to parse such strings manually:

  ```
  var dmyString = '23/4/1999';

  var re = RegExp(
    r'^'
    r'(?<day>[0-9]{1,2})'
    r'/'
    r'(?<month>[0-9]{1,2})'
    r'/'
    r'(?<year>[0-9]{4,})'
    r'$',
  );

  var match = re.firstMatch(dmyString);
  if (match == null) {
    throw FormatException('Unrecognized date format');
  }

  var dateTime4 = DateTime(
    int.parse(match.namedGroup('year')!),
    int.parse(match.namedGroup('month')!),
    int.parse(match.namedGroup('day')!),
  );
  ```

  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63402975/ for another example.

  (I mention using regular expressions for completeness.  There are many more points for failure with this approach, so I do *not* recommend it unless there's no other choice. `DateFormat` or `FixedDateTimeFormatter` usually should be sufficient.)

Comment: DateFormat('d/M/yyyy').parse('2020-10-22 16:17:18'); did not work for me. any suggestion.

Comment: @Kamlesh Of course that didn't work; that format doesn't match the parsed string at all. `d/M/yyyy` means day, month, 4-digit year, separated by slashes.  You want something like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.  However, since that's an ISO format, you could just use `DateTime.parse`.

Comment: Shouldn't something like the fact that "DateFormat cannot parse dates that lack explicit field separators" be at least mentioned in the docs? Seems to me an important note to add...

Comment: For fixed, non-locale dependent dates, try using the [FixedDateTimeFormatter](https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/FixedDateTimeFormatter-class.html)

Comment: @mosuem Thanks for reminding me about `FixedDateTimeFormatter`, which is created after I had originally written this.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime brazilianDate = new DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("11/11/2011");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

you can just use : **`DateTime.parse("your date string");`**

for any extra formating, you can use "Intl" package.

Comment: How does this add anything beyond what the top-voted answers already state?

Comment: Top voted doesn't have the simplest example.

Answer (score 3):

a string can be parsed to DateTime object using Dart default function `DateTime.parse("string");`

```
final parsedDate = DateTime.parse("1974-03-20 00:00:00.000");
```

**[Example on Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev/?b6299aee059e861df29f2a47cbc6dda1)**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  
  var dateValid = "30/08/2020";
  
  print(convertDateTimePtBR(dateValid));
  
}

DateTime convertDateTimePtBR(String validade)
{
   DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse('0001-11-30 00:00:00.000');
  
  List<String> validadeSplit = validade.split('/');
  
  if(validadeSplit.length > 1)
  {
      String day = validadeSplit[0].toString();
      String month = validadeSplit[1].toString(); 
      String year = validadeSplit[2].toString();
    
     parsedDate = DateTime.parse('$year-$month-$day 00:00:00.000');
  }
 
  return parsedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateFormatter(date) {
```

date = date.split('-');
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yMMMd");
String format = dateFormat.format(DateTime(int.parse(date[0]), int.parse(date[1]), int.parse(date[2])));
return format;
}

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers are appreciated. However I would like to introduce the [flutter_helper_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_helper_utils) package's helper method `toDateTime` and `tryToDateTime` which takes dynamic data and atemp to convert it into `DateTime` object (useful when dealing with API data like List or Map<String, dynamic>).

```dart
import 'package:flutter_helper_utils/flutter_helper_utils.dart';
```

```dart
final dateTime = toDateTime('12/11/2020'); // or tryToDateTime

// or specify an optional format and locale.
final dateTime = toDateTime('12/11/2020', format: 'yyyy-MM-dd', locale: 'en_US');

// or if the global method name conflicts with any of your methods.
final dateTime = ConvertObject.toDateTime('12/11/2020');
```

both global methods and static ones behaves the same.

it also contains a lot of useful conversion methods and extensions.

you can check its [documentation website here](https://flutter-helper-utils.web.app)

Answer (score -5):

I solved this by creating, on the C# server side, this attribute:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class DartDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DartDateTimeConverter() 
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFK";
    }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
[JsonConverter(converterType: typeof(DartDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

Internally, the precision is stored, but the Dart app consuming it gets an `ISO8601` format with the right precision.

HTH