# Converting timestamp

Tags: dart, flutter

I couldn't find a solution to this, I'm grabbing data from firebase and one of the fields is a timestamp which looks like this -> 1522129071. How to convert it to a date?

Swift example (works) :

```
func readTimestamp(timestamp: Int) {
    let now = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timestamp))
    let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth])
    let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: date, to: now)
    var timeText = ""

    dateFormatter.locale = .current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"

    if diff.second! <= 0 || diff.second! > 0 && diff.minute! == 0 || diff.minute! > 0 && diff.hour! == 0 || diff.hour! > 0 && diff.day! == 0 {
        timeText = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    if diff.day! > 0 && diff.weekOfMonth! == 0 {
        timeText = (diff.day == 1) ? "\(diff.day!) DAY AGO" : "\(diff.day!) DAYS AGO"
    }
    if diff.weekOfMonth! > 0 {
        timeText = (diff.weekOfMonth == 1) ? "\(diff.weekOfMonth!) WEEK AGO" : "\(diff.weekOfMonth!) WEEKS AGO"
    }

    return timeText
}
```

My attempt at Dart:

```
String readTimestamp(int timestamp) {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var format = new DateFormat('HH:mm a');
    var date = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp);
    var diff = date.difference(now);
    var time = '';

    if (diff.inSeconds <= 0 || diff.inSeconds > 0 && diff.inMinutes == 0 || diff.inMinutes > 0 && diff.inHours == 0 || diff.inHours > 0 && diff.inDays == 0) {
      time = format.format(date); // Doesn't get called when it should be
    } else {
      time = diff.inDays.toString() + 'DAYS AGO'; // Gets call and it's wrong date
    }

    return time;
}
```

And it returns dates/times that are waaaaaaay off.

UPDATE:

```
String readTimestamp(int timestamp) {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var format = new DateFormat('HH:mm a');
    var date = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
    var diff = date.difference(now);
    var time = '';

    if (diff.inSeconds <= 0 || diff.inSeconds > 0 && diff.inMinutes == 0 || diff.inMinutes > 0 && diff.inHours == 0 || diff.inHours > 0 && diff.inDays == 0) {
      time = format.format(date);
    } else {
      if (diff.inDays == 1) {
        time = diff.inDays.toString() + 'DAY AGO';
      } else {
        time = diff.inDays.toString() + 'DAYS AGO';
      }
    }

    return time;
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to assume your timestamp is in the wrong format. What does your timestamp int data look like? (This will tell us if its in seconds. Milliseconds or Microseconds.

Comment: I have the app for ios running on my phone and it shows the correct formatted date. Using the same timestamp from the same database it's giving weird values in dart/flutter. It looks like this -> 1522129071. NOTE** All the timestamps are for some reason showing as the same.

Comment: -> 1522129071 <-  ???

Comment: When I grab that from the database it shows correctly with the swift code, but in dart it shows 19:25 PM where it should be showing 15:50 PM, 2 weeks ago, 4 weeks ago, etc...

Comment: canyou show me screenshot of firebase timestamp? are you using timestamp data type or you just putting miliseconds?

Comment: there is timestamp option in firestore. you would just pass DateTime as as data in your query.

Comment: 1527796211 is what it generally looks like. An int value from firebase.

Comment: Using the Realtime Database, not Firestore.

Comment: For reference, the function `firebaseTimestamp.toDate()` will also convert it to  DateTime.

Comment: Just to update the answer, you can now use compareTo function from the DateTime class. ie: date1.compareTo(date2). Will return -1 if having date1 before today, 0 if having the same date and +1 if having date1 greater than today.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Your timestamp format is in fact in Seconds (Unix timestamp) as opposed to microseconds. If so the answer is as follows:

Change:

```dart
var date = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp);
```

to

```dart
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: Nope, it's still showing wrong values. For example where it should be showing 15:50 PM it's showing 11:23 AM for the same value of 1527796211

Comment: maybe adjust for UTC

Comment: @MohamedMohamed What time zone are you in? 1527796211 should equate to 05/31/2018 @ 7:50pm UTC (Which in my code if you set time zone to UTC to does), also if its 23 mins, did you use Milliseconds?

Comment: You still have Microseconds. Note that Alex has changed it to **Milliseconds**

Comment: EST (UTC−05:00) is my timezone. How can I set the locate to where the person is?

Comment: @MohamedMohamed Dart should do that automatically. Can we see your code now?

Comment: Also where it should be calling the else part it's not. It's all showing the in the HH:mm a format. Where it should be saying 2 weeks ago it says 10:59 AM

Comment: @MohamedMohamed Should be `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` NOT `fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch`

Comment: AH THAT WORKED! Aha, didn't see that lol. But it's all coming out as "HH:mm a" format Some of the days are older so I want to show as Days ago, weeks ago, month ago etc.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed based on your rules only a time in the future would meet the else condition. `diff.inSeconds <= 0` AKA anything in the past. Walk through your rules as if you were the computer and decide what would happen.

Comment: I don't get it, I have the same if/else condition in swift and it works fine why is it different in Dart?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172184/discussion-between-alex-haslam-and-mohamed-mohamed).

Comment: My guess is that you are using diffrence in the opisite order to what you want to?
Try swap var diff = date.difference(now); with var diff = now.difference(date);

Comment: This did not work for me. Got an error " 'int' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'" . This one worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996707/flutter-app-error-type-timestamp-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-datetime

Comment: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(firebasetimestampfieldname.seconds * 1000) will solve your problem. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: `firebasetimestampfieldname.seconds` should be integer.

Answer (score 94):

- **From milliseconds:**

  ```dart
  var millis = 978296400000;
  var dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millis);

  // 12 Hour format:
  var d12 = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(dt); // 12/31/2000, 10:00 PM

  // 24 Hour format:
  var d24 = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm').format(dt); // 31/12/2000, 22:00
  ```
- **From Firestore:**

  ```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> map = docSnapshot.data()!;
  DateTime dt = (map['timestamp'] as Timestamp).toDate();
  ```
- **Converting one format to other:**

  - *12 Hour to 24 Hour:*

    ```dart
    var input = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').parse('12/31/2000, 10:00 PM');
    var output = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm').format(input); // 31/12/2000, 22:00
    ```
  - *24 Hour to 12 Hour:*

    ```dart
    var input = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm').parse('31/12/2000, 22:00');
    var output = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(input); // 12/31/2000, 10:00 PM
    ```

<sub>Use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package (for formatting)</sub>

Answer (score 45):

Full code for anyone who needs it:

```
String readTimestamp(int timestamp) {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var format = DateFormat('HH:mm a');
    var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
    var diff = now.difference(date);
    var time = '';

    if (diff.inSeconds <= 0 || diff.inSeconds > 0 && diff.inMinutes == 0 || diff.inMinutes > 0 && diff.inHours == 0 || diff.inHours > 0 && diff.inDays == 0) {
      time = format.format(date);
    } else if (diff.inDays > 0 && diff.inDays < 7) {
      if (diff.inDays == 1) {
        time = diff.inDays.toString() + ' DAY AGO';
      } else {
        time = diff.inDays.toString() + ' DAYS AGO';
      }
    } else {
      if (diff.inDays == 7) {
        time = (diff.inDays / 7).floor().toString() + ' WEEK AGO';
      } else {

        time = (diff.inDays / 7).floor().toString() + ' WEEKS AGO';
      }
    }

    return time;
  }
```

Thank you Alex Haslam for the help!

Answer (score 25):

if anyone come here to convert firebase `Timestamp` here this will help

```
Timestamp time;
DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(time.microsecondsSinceEpoch)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what was needed. 
Note: If someone is debugging using an emulator, please be sure that it matches your system datetime else accurate time would not be produced

Answer (score 16):

If you are using firestore (and not just storing the timestamp as a string) a date field in a document will return a Timestamp. The Timestamp object contains a `toDate()` method.

Using timeago you can create a relative time quite simply:

```
_ago(Timestamp t) {
  return timeago.format(t.toDate(), 'en_short');
}

build() {
  return  Text(_ago(document['mytimestamp'])));
}
```

Make sure to set `_firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);` to return a Timestamp instead of a Date object.

Answer (score 14):

To convert Firestore `Timestamp` to `DateTime` object just use `.toDate()` method.

Example:

```
Timestamp now = Timestamp.now();
DateTime dateNow = now.toDate();
```

As you can see in [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp/toDate.html)

Answer (score 11):

Just make sure to multiply by the right factor:

**Micro:** multiply by **1000000** (which is 10 power 6)

**Milli:** multiply by **1000** (which is 10 power 3)

This is what it should look like in **Dart**:

```
var date = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000000);
```

Or

```
var date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: I have "Timestamp(seconds=1623775912, nanoseconds=94580000)" how to convert it to DateTime? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: From the documentation there is a method toDateTime(). check here: https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast_timestamp/Timestamp-class.html

Comment: Yes dear, thanks - https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast_timestamp/Timestamp/toDateTime.html

Answer (score 10):

**How to implement:**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

getCustomFormattedDateTime(String givenDateTime, String dateFormat) {
    // dateFormat = 'MM/dd/yy';
    final DateTime docDateTime = DateTime.parse(givenDateTime);
    return DateFormat(dateFormat).format(docDateTime);
}
```

**How to call:**

```
getCustomFormattedDateTime('2021-02-15T18:42:49.608466Z', 'MM/dd/yy');
```

**Result:**

02/15/21

Above code solved my problem. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: I’m using this. works great. Is there a way we can tweak this to convert from UTC to local?

Answer (score 8):

meh, just use https://github.com/andresaraujo/timeago.dart library; it does all the heavy-lifting for you.

EDIT:

From your question, it seems you wanted relative time conversions, and the **timeago** library enables you to do this in 1 line of code. Converting Dates isn't something I'd choose to implement myself, as there are a lot of edge cases & it gets fugly quickly, especially if you need to support different locales in the future.  More code you write = more you have to test.

```
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;

final fifteenAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(minutes: 15));
print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo)); // 15 minutes ago
print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'en_short')); // 15m
print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'es'));

// Add a new locale messages
timeago.setLocaleMessages('fr', timeago.FrMessages());

// Override a locale message
timeago.setLocaleMessages('en', CustomMessages());

print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo)); // 15 min ago
print(timeago.format(fifteenAgo, locale: 'fr')); // environ 15 minutes
```

to convert epochMS to DateTime, just use...

```
final DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1546553448639);
```

Comment: how can i convert date if i have "2021-01-03T18:42:49.608466Z" timestamp? Please suggest.

Comment: I haven't tried it, and you'll need to play with exact date format, but it'll probably go something like this...
`final dt = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssssZ").parse("2021-01-03T18:42:49.608466Z");`

Comment: [Convert String to Date in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Comment: `DateTime.now()` has `subtract` function to compare other `DateTime` typed value helped me to compare 2 datetimes. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this will help anyone. The previous messages have helped me so I'm here to suggest a few things:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

    DateTime convertTimeStampToDateTime(int timeStamp) {
     var dateToTimeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp * 1000);
     return dateToTimeStamp;
   }

  String convertTimeStampToHumanDate(int timeStamp) {
    var dateToTimeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp * 1000);
    return DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(dateToTimeStamp);
  }

   String convertTimeStampToHumanHour(int timeStamp) {
     var dateToTimeStamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp * 1000);
     return DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dateToTimeStamp);
   }

   int constructDateAndHourRdvToTimeStamp(DateTime dateTime, TimeOfDay time ) {
     final constructDateTimeRdv = dateTimeToTimeStamp(DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, dateTime.day, time.hour, time.minute)) ;
     return constructDateTimeRdv;
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the field in timestamp firestore is called timestamp, in dart you could call the toDate() method on the returned map.

```
// Map from firestore
// Using flutterfire package hence the returned data()
Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data();
DateTime _timestamp = data['timestamp'].toDate();
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply call this method to return your desired DateTime value in String.

```
String parseTimeStamp(int value) {
    var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(value * 1000);
    var d12 = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a').format(date);
    return d12;
}
```

Example: if you pass the TimeStamp value `1636786003`, you will get the result as

```
13-11-2021, 12:16 PM
```

Comment: there is one problem with it 
the php date function shows that
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", '1636786003');
is 
"2021-11-13 07:46:43
but this function shows time as 
11-12-2021, 10:46PM
why there is a 3 hour gap between these 2?

Comment: @Harris, Sorry Harish It was my typing mistake . I have edited  my code now . You can chek it . For more info visit this dateformat class https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are here to just convert Timestamp into DateTime,

```
Timestamp timestamp = widget.firebaseDocument[timeStampfield];
DateTime date = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch).toDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested this one and it works

```
// Map from firestore
// Using flutterfire package hence the returned data()
Map<String, dynamic> data = documentSnapshot.data();
DateTime _timestamp = data['timestamp'].toDate();
```

Test details can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_X8J7uBPNw&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2):

Print DateTime, TimeStamp as string from Firebase Firestore:

```
      Timestamp t;
      String s;
      DateTime d;
//Declaring Variables
      snapshots.data.docs[index]['createdAt'] is Timestamp
                                    ? t = snapshots.data.docs[index]['createdAt']
                                    : s =
      snapshots.data.docs[index]['createdAt'].toString();
            
                                //check createdAt field Timestamp or DateTime
      snapshots.data.docs[index]['createdAt'] is Timestamp
                                    ? d = t.toDate()
                                    : s =
                                        snapshots.data.docs[index]['createdAt'].toString();
            
                                print(s.toString()); //Print Date and Time if DateTime
        print(d.toString()); //Print Date and Time if TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 2):

Long num format date into Calender format from:

```
var responseDate = 1637996744;
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(responseDate);
//to format date into different types to display;
// sample format: MM/dd/yyyy : 11/27/2021
var dateFormatted = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').format(date);
// sample format: dd/MM/yyy : 27/11/2021
var dateFormatted = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(date);
// sample format: dd/MMM/yyyy : 27/Nov/2021
var dateFormatted = DateFormat('dd/MMM/yyyy').format(date);
// sample format: dd/MMMM/yyyy : 27/November/2021
var dateFormatted = DateFormat('dd/MMMM/yyyy').format(date);
print("Date After Format = $dateFormatted");
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've faced the same issue. so I'm using simple logic.
Very simple to ***Convert*** **TimeStamp** to **DateTime**. We can use this *get* **TimeStamp** to **DateTime** format.

[image]

[image]

In this example, I'm using Firebase.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; /// Import this line
TimeStamp timestamp = database.data()["date"] /// Firebase firestore date field value.
//Example Outputs:- Timestamp(seconds=1657706107, nanoseconds=261000000)
DateTime dateTime = timestamp.toDate(); /// It will be return Date and Time Both.
//Example Outputs:- 2022-07-13 15:25:07.261
String dateOnly = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(dateTime); /// It will be only return date DD/MM/YYYY format
//Example Outputs:- 13/07/2022
```

In a single-line code

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; /// Import this line
String dateOnly = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(database.data()["date"].toDate()); /// It will be only return date DD/MM/YYYY format
//Example Outputs:- 13/07/2022
```

Thanks for visiting and pushing my reputation 
Happy Coding Journey...

Answer (score 2):

**2022**

Actually the Flutter team updated the Timestamp object.

Now if you want to convert from Timestamp to DateTime you can just use this code:

```
/*you Timestamp instance*/.toDate()
eg. Timestamp.now().toDate()
```

Viceversa if you want to convert from DateTime to Timestamp you can do:

```
Timestamp.fromDate(/*your DateTime instance*/)
eg. Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())
```

Hope you'll find this helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

All of that above can work but for a quick and easy fix you can use the [time_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/time_formatter) package.

Using this package you can convert the epoch to human-readable time.

```
String convertTimeStamp(timeStamp){
//Pass the epoch server time and the it will format it for you 
   String formatted = formatTime(timeStamp).toString();
   return formatted;
}
//Then you can display it
Text(convertTimeStamp['createdTimeStamp'])//< 1 second : "Just now" up to < 730 days : "1 year"
```

Here you can check the format of the output that is going to be displayed: [Formats](https://pub.dev/packages/time_formatter#format)

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp has [toDate] method then you can use it directly as an DateTime.

```
timestamp.toDate();
// return DateTime object
```

Also there is an stupid way if you want really convert it:

```
DateTime.parse(timestamp.toDate().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

`Assuming you have a class`

```dart
class Dtime {
  int dt;
  Dtime(this.dt);

  String formatYMED() {
    var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(this.dt);
    var formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd().format(date);
    return formattedDate;
  }

  String formatHMA() {
    var time = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(this.dt * 1000);
    final timeFormat = DateFormat('h:mm a', 'en_US').format(time);
    return timeFormat;
  }
```

I am a beginner though, I hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

There are  different ways this can be achieved based on different scenario, see which of the following code fits your scenario.

##### Conversion of `Firebase timestamp` to `DateTime`:

1. ```
   document['timeStamp'].toDate()
   ```
2. ```
   (document["timeStamp"] as Timestamp).toDate()
   ```
3. ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch);
   ```
4. ```
   Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch).toDate();
   ```
5. If `timeStamp` is in `microseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000000);
   ```
6. If `timeStamp` is in `milliseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
   ```
7. Add the following function in your dart file.

   ```
    String formatTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
      var format = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // <- use skeleton here
      return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
    }
   ```

   call it as `formatTimestamp(document['timestamp'])`

Answer (score 0):

// simplest method

```
print(DateTime.now()); // date to be convert
int newt = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
DateTime ndt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(newt);
print(ndt); // return convert date
```

Answer (score 0):

From epoch int number to=> DateTime to=> (yyyy-mm-dd) format
This is working for me

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


void main(){

// int value epoch from API data   
int startDate = 1699302504305;
  
// int to DateTime type  
DateTime startDateToDateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(startDate);
print(startDateToDateTime); // 2023-11-06 15:28:24.305
  
// format the output year -  month -  day 
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');  
final String startDateToDateTimeFormatted = formatter.format(startDateToDateTime);  
print(startDateToDateTimeFormatted); // 2023-11-06
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?