# Flutter app error - type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching data cloud firestore & trying to show in my app by using the following piece of code.

```
new Text(timeago.format(document.data['tripDoc']['docCreatedOn'])),
```

I'm using `timeago` dart package to format that. But, after making updating to latest cloud firestore plugin I'm getting this error -

```
Another exception was thrown: type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'
```

Can't able to understand how to parse this 'TimeStamp' object to 'DateTime'. Because `timeago` plugin need data in DateTime object format.

Answer (score 62):

`.toDate()` worked for me. Now the modified code is -

```
new Text(timeago.format(document.data['tripDoc']['docCreatedOn'].toDate()))
```

Hope, it'll help someone.

Answer (score 27):

add toDate() method .It will work

```
DateTime dateTime = documents[i].data["duedate"].toDate();
```

Answer (score 12):

Ios and Android will not receive same type. Ios receive the timestamps as TimeStamp and Android receive it as DateTime already. So for fixing this issue I just created this little function. This will return a DateTime and let use format it etc.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

DateTime parseTime(dynamic date) {
  return Platform.isIOS ? (date as Timestamp).toDate() : (date as DateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you use [JsonSerializable](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable), Use [JsonConverter](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/example/lib/json_converter_example.dart)

```
class TimestampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime, Timestamp> {
  const TimestampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime fromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
    return timestamp.toDate();
  }

  @override
  Timestamp toJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class User{
  final String id;
  @TimestampConverter()
  final DateTime timeCreated;

  User([this.id, this.timeCreated]);

  factory User.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) =>
      _$UserFromJson(
          documentSnapshot.data..["_id"] = documentSnapshot.documentID);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this)..remove("_id");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is more reliable

```
DateTime updateDateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        map['updatedatetime'].millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

Answer (score 3):

i had the same error because date is inserted as **TimeStamp** type in Firebase Firestore
and i was trying to parse it as if it was **Date** type

this was my model that got me the error when trying to get data from firestore

```
    class Post {
  String title;
  String body;
  String teacherName;
  DateTime date;

  Post({
    required this.title,
    required this.body,
    required this.teacherName,
    required this.date,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
        teacherName: json["teacher"],
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
        "teacher": teacherName,
        "date": date,
      };
}
```

i discovered that firestore has toDate() method in TimeStamp() that transform timestamp to Datetime

so in my code in toJson method i parsed the date field as Timestamp then transform it as DateTime

```
factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        title: json["title"],
        body: json["body"],
        teacherName: json["teacher"],
        date: (json["date"] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp);
DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `document.data["data"].microsecondsSinceEpoch`

This is working for me:-

```
User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document){
dataNasc = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(document.data["data"].microsecondsSinceEpoch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following function will take care of all.

```
DateTime vikiDate(dynamic dateValue) {
  if (dateValue is DateTime) {
    return dateValue;
  } else if (dateValue is String) {
    return DateTime.parse(dateValue);
  }
  else if (dateValue is Timestamp) {
    return dateValue.toDate();
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

Just use it as

```
DateTime acceptedAt = vikiDate(json['accepted_at']);
```

Comment: @Sverrir Torfason : can you tell me, which kind of data types except DateTime, String or Timestamp used? I will look into it...

Answer (score 1):

Firestore is returning a Timestamp object, which consists of seconds and nanoseconds.  Oddly, on iOS you can indeed just use a .toDate() and it works.  But that breaks on Android as toDate() is not a method. So you can do a platform check if you want, but the universal solution is to use Firestore's Timestamp:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

DateTime _convertStamp(Timestamp _stamp) {

  if (_stamp != null) {

    return Timestamp(_stamp.seconds, _stamp.nanoseconds).toDate();

    /*
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return _stamp.toDate();
    } else {
      return Timestamp(_stamp.seconds, _stamp.nanoseconds).toDate();
    }
    */

  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

and then pass your model to it:

```
  SomeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    updatedAt = _convertStamp(parsedJson['updatedAt']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Firebase timestamp field type has the structure:

```
Timestamp (Timestamp(seconds=1561186800, nanoseconds=0))
hashCode:423768083
microsecondsSinceEpoch:1561186800000000
millisecondsSinceEpoch:1561186800000
nanoseconds:0
runtimeType:Type (Timestamp)
seconds:1561186800
_seconds:1561186800
_nanoseconds:0
```

So you can use either micro- or milliseconds:

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['tripDoc']['docCreatedOn'].millisecondsSinceEpoch)
```

or

```
DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(data['tripDoc']['docCreatedOn'].microsecondsSinceEpoch)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are  various ways to convert `TimeStamp to DateTime` which differs based on the scenario.
I have tried to gather all the possible ways to convert `Firebase timeStamp` to `DateTime`. Pick which works for you.

---

##### Conversion of `Firebase timestamp` to `DateTime`:

1. ```
   document['timeStamp'].toDate()
   ```
2. ```
   (document["timeStamp"] as Timestamp).toDate()
   ```
3. ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch);
   ```
4. ```
   Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch).toDate();
   ```
5. If `timeStamp` is in `microseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000000);
   ```
6. If `timeStamp` is in `milliseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
   ```
7. Add the following function in your dart file.

   ```
    String formatTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
      var format = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // <- use skeleton here
      return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
    }
   ```

   call it as `formatTimestamp(document['timestamp'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some funny reason, I can't use toDate() on Android. Have to use it for iOS. So I'm forced to use a platform check like this:

```
Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
  ? DateFormat('dd MMM kk:mm').format(document['timestamp'].toDate())
  : DateFormat('dd MMM kk:mm').format(document['timestamp'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
timeago.format(DateTime.tryParse(timestamp))
```

like in yours it will be

```
  timeago.format(DateTime.tryParse(document.data['tripDoc']['docCreatedOn']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be an error because in the database or firebase there is some type that is missing or different name on

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer a bit? As written here, it seems more like a comment instead of an answer proposing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelavant but for those who use Timestamp (cloud_firestore) instead of DateTime you probably will get

> <String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'

```
class MyUser {
  String uid;
  String email;
  Timestamp firstJoined;
  
  MyUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    this.uid = data['uid'] ?? '';
    this.email = data['email'] ?? '';
    // PARSE FIRESTORE TIMESTAMP
    if (data['firstJoined'] != null) {
        this.firstJoined = Timestamp(
            data['firstJoined']['_seconds'],
            data['firstJoined']['_nanoseconds'],
        );
    } else {
        this.firstJoined=null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in my model class for that error.

from Backend, I'm getting this response

```
"reported_date": "2021-02-19T05:45:57.434150Z",
```

change from

```
reportedDate = json['reported_date']
```

to

```
reportedDate = json['reported_date'] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json['reported_date'] as String);
```

This solves my problem.

After parsing you can use any formate
[to read about formates](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Below some of the example, I'm testing for reference

```
///return in 12:08 PM format
static String returnTime(DateTime dt) {
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('h:mm a');
  String time = formatter.format(dt);
  return time;
}

///return in Thu, Feb 18 format
String returnDate(DateTime dt) {
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('EEE, MMM d');
  String date = formatter.format(dt);
  return date;
}

///return day (Thu, Feb 18, will return 18)
String standaloneDay(DateTime dt) {
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('c');
  String date = formatter.format(dt);
  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### if you using firestorm and getting (QuerySnapshot)

i use this line to get date from firestore:

```
postDate: doc.data().toString().contains('postDate') ? doc.get('postDate') :  DateTime.now()
```

in this method:

```
List<AdModel?>? _adModelListFromQuerySnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    try {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        return PostModel(
       title: doc.data().toString().contains('title') ? doc.get('title') :'', 
       description: doc.data().toString().contains('description') ?doc.get('description') :  '',
       adDate: doc.data().toString().contains('adDate') ? doc.get('adDate') :  DateTime.now(),
        );
      }).toList();
    } catch (error) {
      print(' Show ${error.toString()}');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

#### This is my Model

```
PostModel {
DateTime? postDate;

PostModel({this.postDate}); 
}
```

I wish this is helpful

Answer (score -1):

For the record, if you're using freezed, this worked for me:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'activity_card_model.freezed.dart';
part 'activity_card_model.g.dart';

DateTime _createdAtFromJson(Timestamp timestamp) => timestamp.toDate();
Timestamp _createdAtToJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);
DateTime _updatedAtFromJson(Timestamp timestamp) => timestamp.toDate();
Timestamp _updatedAtToJson(DateTime date) => Timestamp.fromDate(date);

@freezed
abstract class ActivityCard implements _$ActivityCard {
  const ActivityCard._();

  const factory ActivityCard({
    @Default(true) bool active,
    @Default('other') String category,
    @JsonKey(name: 'created_at', fromJson: _createdAtFromJson, toJson: _createdAtToJson)
        required DateTime createdAt,
    required String description,
    required String heading,
    String? id,
    @JsonKey(name: 'image_name') @Default('') String imageName,
    @JsonKey(name: 'img_src') @Default('') String imageURL,
    @JsonKey(name: 'link') String? linkURL,
    @JsonKey(name: 'link_description') String? linkDescription,
    String? subheading,
    @JsonKey(name: 'updated_at', fromJson: _updatedAtFromJson, toJson: _updatedAtToJson)
        required DateTime updatedAt,
  }) = _ActivityCard;

  factory ActivityCard.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = doc.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return ActivityCard.fromJson(json);
  }

  factory ActivityCard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ActivityCardFromJson(json);

  factory ActivityCard.fromDocument(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    final data = doc.data()!;
    return ActivityCard.fromJson(data).copyWith(id: doc.id);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toDocument() => toJson()..remove('id');
}
```