# How to convert Timestamp to DateTime from firebase with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have Timestamp item in firebase. I get the item from dart code timestamp type.
It shows like 'Timestamp(seconds=1590903768, nanoseconds=26999000)' as it is.

I would like to show on my Application only Date like '2020-06-01' or '06-01'.

Please give me advice.

Comment: I'm not a dart expert, but does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart

Comment: This page should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996707/flutter-app-error-type-timestamp-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-datetime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/dart-flutter-converting-timestamp

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Timestamp` class has a `toDate` function that converts it to a `DateTime` object. See [this](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html) for more information. Any formatting you want to do in converting it to a string can be done more easily now with `intl` package formatters.

Example:

```
Timestamp stamp = Timestamp.now();
DateTime date = stamp.toDate();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the `Timestamp` DataType to `DateTime` and then format the DateTime according to your requirements.

Note: To make this code work, you must install the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) in your Flutter project. and change the skeleton based on how you want to format it.

**Example**

add the following method in your dart file.

```
String formatTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
  var format = new DateFormat('y-M-d'); // <- use skeleton here
  return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
}
```

then get the TimeStamp from FireStore and pass it into this method

```
print(formatTimestamp(doc.data['timestamp']));
```

**OutPut**

```
year-month-day
```

For other available formats, use Skeleton to format.

```
 ICU Name                   Skeleton
 --------                   --------
 DAY                          d
 ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
 WEEKDAY                      EEEE
 ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
 STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
 NUM_MONTH                    M
 NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
 NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
 ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
 ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
 ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
 MONTH                        MMMM
 MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
 MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
 ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
 QUARTER                      QQQQ
 YEAR                         y
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
 YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
 YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
 YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
 YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
 HOUR24                       H
 HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
 HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
 HOUR                         j
 HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
 HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
 MINUTE                       m
 MINUTE_SECOND                ms
 SECOND                       s
```

I hope this will be helpful!!

Comment: The actual timestamp saved on Firestore is 13-Nov-21, but after using this code, the date shown is 13-10-21 (13-Oct-21). How to fix this..??

Comment: I got the answer, `DateFormat('d-MM-y')` will show November as 10, and Jan as 0, because the counting starts from 0. So, instead I used, `DateFormat('d-MMM-y')`, it shows 13-Nov-21, and not 13-10-21.

Answer (score 1):

You get back a map from firestore. Assuming you have named it "creationDate", you can convert the returned timestamp to a DateTime object using the toDate() dart function. The "simplest" way to format the datetime is to use the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

```
// Map From firestore
Map data = documentSnapshot.data();
var creationDate = data['creationDate'].toDate();

//Format using intl package
DateFormat _dateFormat = DateFormat('y-MM-d');
String formattedDate =  _dateFormat.format(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want **Hours and minutes(hh:mm)** from timestamp, Simply create following method which gives you string in return.

```
String convertTimestampToHm(Timestamp timestamp) {
var format = DateFormat('Hm'); // convert into hours and minutes
return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
```

}

**NOTE:** - You can always use **Skeleton** base on requiremrnt.

Answer (score 0):

There are  different ways to convert `TimeStamp to DateTime` which differs based on the scenario.
I have summarize all the possible ways, Pick the one which suits your case !!

---

##### Conversion of `Firebase timestamp` to `DateTime`:

1. ```
   document['timeStamp'].toDate()
   ```
2. ```
   (document["timeStamp"] as Timestamp).toDate()
   ```
3. ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch);
   ```
4. ```
   Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(document['timeStamp'].millisecondsSinceEpoch).toDate();
   ```
5. If `timeStamp` is in `microseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000000);
   ```
6. If `timeStamp` is in `milliseconds` use:

   ```
   DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
   ```
7. Add the following function in your dart file.

   ```
    String formatTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
      var format = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // <- use skeleton here
      return format.format(timestamp.toDate());
    }
   ```

   call it as `formatTimestamp(document['timestamp'])`