# How to convert firestore doc data having timestamp field into the data class generated through Freezed dart package?

Tags: flutter, dart

Structure of My Dto is like -

```
@freezed
abstract class MessageDto with _$MessageDto{
  factory MessageDto({
    String message,
    @JsonKey(name: 'message_type') String messageType,
    @JsonKey(name: 'sender_id') String senderId,
    @JsonKey(name: 'sent_at') Timestamp sendAt,
    }) = _MessageDto;

  factory MessageDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = doc.data;
    return MessageDto.fromJson(json);
  }
  factory MessageDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MessageDtoFromJson(json);
}
```

1. The generator is not supporting TimeStamp data type.
2. When I am using DateTime dataType, it is generating code but throwing exception on parsing the documentSnaphot data as

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having the same exact problem and looking for a solution.

Comment: Found a solution, see the answer below.

Comment: I'm crossposting from another thread... See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67962150/7183998

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a custom `fromJson` and `toJson` function to the `@JsonKey`.
https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/JsonKey.html

```
Timestamp _sendAtFromJson(Timestamp timestamp) => timestamp;

@freezed
abstract class MessageDto with _$MessageDto{
  factory MessageDto({
    String message,
    @JsonKey(name: 'message_type') String messageType,
    @JsonKey(name: 'sender_id') String senderId,
    @JsonKey(name: 'sent_at', fromJson: _sendAtFromJson) Timestamp sendAt,
    }) = _MessageDto;

  factory MessageDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> json = doc.data;
    return MessageDto.fromJson(json);
  }
  factory MessageDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MessageDtoFromJson(json);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its better to convert the timestamp to datetime

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final notificationModel = notificationModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'notification_model.freezed.dart';
part 'notification_model.g.dart';

NotificationModel notificationModelFromJson(String str) =>
    NotificationModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String notificationModelToJson(NotificationModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

@freezed
abstract class NotificationModel with _$NotificationModel {
  const factory NotificationModel({
    String? title,
    String? uid,
    String? description,
    @JsonKey(name: 'createdOn', fromJson: _sendAtFromJson) DateTime? createdOn,
  }) = _NotificationModel;

  factory NotificationModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NotificationModelFromJson(json);
}

DateTime _sendAtFromJson(Timestamp timestamp) =>
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case only from json method was not enough .. I wanted to convert from / to json using millisecondsFromEpoch:

```
Timestamp _timestampFromJson(int timestamp) => Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp);
int _timestampToJson(Timestamp timestamp) => timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch ;
```

and in your freezed field that has the type Timestamp :

```
@JsonKey(name: 'key_name', fromJson: _timestampFromJson , toJson: _timestampToJson)
```