# How to format an integer to ss:m

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the following format from an int: `ss:m` (s = seconds, m = milliseconds) from a countdown timer. If there are minutes, the format should be `mm:ss:m`.

Here's my code:

```
final int currentTime = 100; // 10 seconds
final Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
    Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer _timer) {
      if (currentTime <= 0) {
        _timer.cancel();
      } else {
        currentTime--;
        print(currentTime);
      }
});
```

I tried adding `currentTime` to a `Duration` as milliseconds but it didn't give me the desired results. What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to the correct format?

Comment: [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/dart-flutter-converting-timestamp)

Comment: check my answer what you have done is time conversion mistake

Answer (score 0):

try `Duration.toString()` it'll give you a string formatted in your requirement
more precisely

```
Duration(milliseconds:currentTime).toString()
```

and 100 millis is not 10 seconds

**10000 millis is 10 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below method the get it in hh:mm:ss / mm:ss format, you can tweak to get in s:mm

```
String getTime(int milis) {
    Duration position = Duration(milliseconds: milis);
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }

    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(position.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(position.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    String time;
    if (twoDigits(position.inHours) == "00") {
      time = "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
    } else {
      time = "${twoDigits(position.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
    }
    return time;
  }
```