# Get years months days hours minutes seconds from Firestore timestamp

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to display how many years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds passed using a timestamp from Firestore which is set using `"timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. Ideally the seconds would increment and update the minutes, hours and so on. Just like a stopwatch.

Are there any plugins available or examples that I can use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart/Flutter : Converting timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/dart-flutter-converting-timestamp)

Comment: I wanted something like this https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer but with months and years and days added to it.