# TimeStamp to DateTime conversion Firebase to Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Straight to the issue. I am new to Firebase Firestore.

I have model:

```
     @JsonSerializable()
      class CategoryEntity extends Equatable {
       final String id;
       final String name;
       @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJson, toJson: _toJson)
       final DateTime createdDate;
       @JsonKey(fromJson: _fromJson, toJson: _toJson)
       final DateTime updatedDate; 
       final String description;

    const CategoryEntity(
      this.id,
      this.name,
      this.createdDate,
      this.updatedDate,
      this.description,
    );
```

The data that is to be saved in Firebase Firestore is Timestamp for `createDate` and `updatedDate`.

But the problem is that I cannot convert the data from Firebase to local. The save method converts the `dateCreate` to Timestamp fine.

```
     static DateTime _fromJson(int int) =>
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int);
      static int _toJson(DateTime time) => time.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to show the ServerTimeStamp to the user local time.

I have two ways you can check,

One using this package [timeformatter](https://pub.dev/packages/time_formatter), will show you the time according to the users time.

```
A mini truth table for the format of the value returned by the function:
< 1 second : "Just now"
< 60 seconds : "X seconds" (2-59)
< 2 minutes : "1 minute"
< 60 minutes : "X minutes" (2-59)
< 2 hours : "1 hour"
< 24 hours : "X hours" (2-23)
< 2 days : "1 day"
< 7 days : "X days" (2-6)
< 2 weeks : "1 week"
< 28 days : "X weeks" (2-3)
< 30.44 * 1.5 days : "1 month"
< 365 - 15.22 days : "X months" (2-12)
< 730 days : "1 year"
Rest: "X years"
```

Two, you can use this package to change it [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

int timeInMillis = 1586348737122; //no need to convert it just set the timestamp here.
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeInMillis);
var formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date); //
```

you can see the answer on this post for more info [Dart/Flutter : Converting timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50632217/9949983)

Comment: Thanks!, but the problem persist cannot convert TimeStamp to DateTime. exception occurs. This mainly occurs from firebase firestore collection save the data as timestamp.