# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, web

I am relatively new to flutter. I have been dealing with flutter code base written by previous developer. So whenever i navigate to history page in the app it throws exception stating type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'. I have no clue what's wrong with the code. any help would be apprecated. I have been stuck for a couple of days now. type of createddate is string.[image]

```
            docs.documents.forEach((i) {
              Timestamp date = i.data['createddate'];
              DateTime dates = date.toDate();
              DateFormat inputFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
              DateTime parsedDate = inputFormat.parse(dates.toString());
              print(approvestatus + 'dada');
              if ((filterFrom
                          .subtract(Duration(hours: 24))
                          .isBefore(parsedDate) &&
                      filterTo
                          .add(Duration(hours: 24))
                          .isAfter(parsedDate)) &&
                  (i.data['shopkeeperid'].toString() == uid) &&
                  (i.data['productid']
                          .toString()
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(searchvalue.toString()) ||
                      i.data['productname']
                          .toString()
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(searchvalue.toString()) ||
                      i.data['productbrand']
                          .toString()
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(searchvalue.toString()) ||
                      i.data['availablequantity']
                          .toString()
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .contains(searchvalue.toString()) ||
                      searchvalue == "")) {
                childrenWidgets.add(productView(i, context));
              }
            });
```

Comment: What do you not understand ? you cannot do `Timestamp date = "some string"` even if some string is a formated date ...

Comment: Correct @Selvin how should i fix this any thoughts?

Comment: obviously you don't need `date` nor `dates` and parse it directly ...

Answer (score 1):

there is a timeStamp variable in your code and you are trying to pass a string to it.
I cannot clearly understand this code. but you got to put debug point on every line.
for example first line

```
      Timestamp date = i.data['createddate'];
```

if the `data['createddate'];` is a string it can make this error
put the debug point and you can see each value and you will also be able to understand from which point your code won't move forward

Comment: thanks for the reply. i did put a debugger. 
after this line
      Timestamp date = i.data['createddate'];
it throws the exception .
type of createddate is string. and it is been assigned to type of timestamp.

Comment: @Aniket so from your code i think you should change the String in data to timeStamp
this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/dart-flutter-converting-timestamp
or you may just want to change that timeStamp to a String

Comment: Thanks mate that link was super usefull. Really appreciate it.