# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart, date-formatting

I tried calling this code:

```
var test = int.parse(DateFormat('yyyy').format(formattedTemporaryDate));
```

but I get the error:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'
```

my `formattedTemporaryDate` is `'2022-01-08'`

I think I need to transform the formattedTemporaryDate to an int, but I don't know how. And I even don't know if this really is the problem... Do you need more information to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `DateTime.parse('2022-01-08')` instead of just `String`.

Something like `var formattedTemporaryDate = DateTime.parse('2022-01-08');`

Answer (score 1):

What would you like var `test` to be at the end? A datetime? An int representation of the date?

You can convert your string to a `DateTime` object by calling DateTime.parse()

```
  var formattedTemporaryDate = '2022-01-08';
  DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(formattedTemporaryDate);
  print(dt); // 2022-01-08 00:00:00.000
```

If you then want to convert it to an `Int` (maybe because you're doing UNIX Timestamp stuff?) You could try reverse-engineering some of the code people added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/converting-timestamp) going the other direction.