# How to change milliseconds to date

Tags: flutter

`AppoinmentList` page - which part I need to add code for this page for change milisec to date. Someone can help me?
appointmentUnixTime": 1646274840000,

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'api_service.dart';


class AppoinmentList extends StatefulWidget {
  int ts = 1646274840000;
  final String? token;
  AppoinmentList({
    Key? key,
    this.token,
  }) :super(key: key);

@override
_AppoinmentListState createState() => _AppoinmentListState();
  
  
}
class _AppoinmentListState extends State<AppoinmentList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    APIService.getAppointmentList(widget.token!);
  
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Appointment Listing"),
      ),
      body: _appoinmentListUI(),
    );
  }
  _appoinmentListUI() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: APIService.getAppointmentList(widget.token!),
    
    builder: (
      
      BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<String?> model,
    ){
      if (model.hasData) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text("Token",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            ),
            Text(widget.token!),
            Text("Response Message",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            ),
            Text(model.data!),
            
          ],
        );
      }
      
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  );
  }
}
```

I success to call token but I don't know which part I need to add code for change milisec to date. I knew using flutter. Can someone tell me?

[This my query from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvuXG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/converting-timestamp

Answer (score 6):

You can use Following code to convert millisec to date:-

```
int ts = 1646274840000;
var dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts);

var date = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(dt);
print(date);
```

Output:

```
03/03/2022, 08:04 AM
```

Comment: Which part I need to enter var date = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(dt);
print(date); ? For int ts = 1646274840000;
var dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts); it's for declaration right?

Comment: In initState().

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple line to convert

```
   var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);
```