# InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to convert a firebase timestamp that has been returned from a could function to a date object in flutter.

I already tried those solutions but they didn't work:
[Converting timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632217/converting-timestamp)

Here is the code I am using:

```dart
await firebaseFunctions
          .httpsCallable('functionName')
          .call({"data": data}).then((value) {
             Map<String, dynamic> map = value.data;
              DateTime dt = (map['dateOfPurchase'] as Timestamp).toDate();
              print(dt);
          });
```

The `data` that the `map['dateOfPurchase']` attribut containes: `{_nanoseconds: 665000000, _seconds: 1659266068}`

The `exception` i get :

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of
> type 'Timestamp' in type cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem with this code

```dart
 await firebaseFunctions
          .httpsCallable('functionName')
          .call({"data": data}).then((value) {
            
             final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(value.data['dateOfPurchase']);
             final seconds  = map["_seconds"];
             final nanoseconds  = map["_nanoseconds"];
             final Timestamp postConverted = Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds);
             print(postConverted.toDate());
          });
```

Result of the `print`: `2022-07-31 13:14:28.665`

I hope that could help some people who face the same problem then me.

If someone has a better solution don't hesitate to share it.