# How format api wordpress date in flutter

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter

I work on flutter api wordpress project . How format date from wordpress api . date came in this format (2019-08-26T16:23:06) . i want to remove second and year . and month like (June , April)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/intl and DateFormat :

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(data[index]['date']);
String dateformat = DateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DateFormat object that fit your needs and use it to format your date.

Head over to the documentation to examples: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: Since the string is already formatted in ISO9601 format, `DateTime.parse()` is all that's needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with this function

```
  timenow() {
                                  var day = DateTime.parse(
                                          snapshot.data[index].date)
                                      .day;
                                  var month = DateTime.parse(
                                          snapshot.data[index].date)
                                      .month;
                                  var year = DateTime.parse(
                                          snapshot.data[index].date)
                                      .year;
                                  var hour = DateTime.parse(
                                          snapshot.data[index].date)
                                      .hour;
                                  var min = DateTime.parse(
                                          snapshot.data[index].date)
                                      .minute;
                                  return year.toString() +
                                      "/" +
                                      month.toString() +
                                      "/" +
                                      day.toString() +
                                      "   " +
                                      hour.toString() +
                                      ":" +
                                      min.toString();
                                } // format date and time
```