# Darts.. How to convert a date string to timestamp

Tags: dart

I am using dart/flutter and need some help on how format date . How do  I parse the following string to a timestamp

2019-08-22T00:40:57.166+0000

Basically, I want to get the timestamp for the above date and pass it to timeago to format

Thanks

Comment: [`DateTime.parse`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html)/[`DateTime.tryParse`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will take your string and convert it to milliseconds since epoch (I assume that's what you mean by timestamp:

```
String dateStr = '2019-08-22T00:40:57.166+0000';
DateTime date = DateTime.parse(dateStr);
print("The timestamp for date '$dateStr' is ${date.millisecondsSinceEpoch}");
```

The output of the above program is:

```
The timestamp for date '2019-08-22T00:40:57.166+0000' is 1566434457166
```

Good luck!  :)