# Parse from timestamp

Tags: parsing, flutter, dart, timestamp

I am trying to parse data and time from an API about a certain Schedule, the response I'm getting is of the form " 2019-10-09T13:00:00.000Z " and " 2019-10-09T14:30:00.000Z ".

How to obtain the date and time from this in Dart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.tryParse()](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/DateTime/tryParse.html). It will return null if the input can’t be parsed to a datetime object. But the format you receive should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date and time like substring

```
  DateTime follow = DateTime.parse("${f.followDate.substring(6,10)}-${f.followDate.substring(3,5)}-${f.followDate.substring(0,2)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert to DateTime object, it will automatically parse time

```
Datetime d1= DateTime.parse(strDate);
```

then connvert to time required by you

```
 String date = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm').format(d1);
```