# Dart - Formated string date to Datetime

Tags: dart

I have this formatted string date

**2020/04/16** (YYYY/MM/DD)

I want to parse this string to Datetime

```
var string= 2020/04/16
DateTime.parse(string);
```

Obviusly doesn´t work, doesn´t has a date correct format.

Somebody know what is the best way to parse this string to DateTime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/179715)

Comment: Is corrrect in parse but when i try to convert to Date like this "DateTime.parse(DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').parse(string))" return The argument type 'DateTime' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: `DateFormat.parse` already returns a `DateTime`. You don't need to parse it again.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
String date = '20180626170555
String dateWithT = date.substring(0, 8) + 'T' + date.substring(8);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateWithT);
```

or you try this:

```
savedDateString = "2012-02-27 13:27:00"
DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(savedDateString);
```