# Dart - Extract Date (MM/DD/YYYY) from a String

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working in Firebase and writing a Cloud Function in JavaScript. I am trying to extract a `Month Day, Year` string from a Firebase Timestamp (from my database).

In my Cloud Function I use `timestampObj.toDate().toString()` and it returns a string like this in my client-side: 
`Fri Dec 06 2019 18:06:52 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

How do I get the string `December 6, 2019` from the line above in my Dart code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Comment: No, it does not @jamesdlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this help? Shouldn't the output be "December 6, 2019" instead of December 9?

```js
var date = new Date("Fri Dec 06 2019 18:06:52 GMT+0000 (UTC)");  //

var result = date.toLocaleString('default',{month:'long'})+" "+date.getDate()+", "+date.getFullYear();

console.log(result);   // "December 6, 2019"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but for some reason the Month string that is returned to me says "M12" instead of December like yours does. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @MaryX Strange. I tried it again with `var date = new Date();` as an input to today's date and output was correct `May 24, 2020`

Comment: Never mind, I just changed the 'default' to 'en-US'. @Mohsen Alyafei

Answer (score 2):

Converting the DateTime returned by `toDate()` into a String sounds like putting yourself through much more trouble than necessary.  [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) has lots of methods for easily extracting the calendar components out of it.  You can see from that API doc link that it has properties for [year](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/year.html), [month](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/month.html), and [day](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/day.html) that require no text parsing.  It should be trivial to convert those into the string format you want.

Even better, you can just use the [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class.