# Flutter : get difference of two formatted time values using ".difference()" function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the time difference of two time values , one coming from a json object in the format of

```
DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

and the other is from

```
DateTime.now()
```

. Since `DateTime.now()` is coming in this format "2020-06-23 08:10:36.411419" including the microseconds.

In which case I cannot get the difference of these two time values because value coming from json has no microseconds.

So I have to format the DateTime.now() value to match the json value.(cleaningStartTime is the value coming from json)

So I wrote this code

```
var formatTime =  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  var timeNow = formatTime.format(DateTime.now());
  var diff = timeNow.difference(cleaningStartTime);
```

[code from Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmDS2.png)

But when i try to return the "diff" value it gives me this error.

> The method 'difference' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'difference'.
> var diff = timeNow.difference(cleaningStartTime);

How do I approach to fix this issue ?

flutter version = v1.17.1

Comment: `DateTime.difference` computes the difference between two `DateTime` objects, but you're trying to call it on a `String`.  Just use `DateTime.now().difference(cleaningStartTime)`. Just because one of the times doesn't have microseconds doesn't prevent you from computing the time difference.

Comment: HI jamedin. Thanks for the reply. I tried that way but it gives this error.                   
       "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'"                                                                   
      var diff = DateTime.now().difference(cleaningStartTime);

Comment: Then `cleaningStartTime` is also not a `DateTime` object.  You would need to use `DateFormat.parse` ([or something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/179715)) to convert it to a `DateTime` object first.