# How to convert RSS pubDate string to DateTime in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, rss

I'm kei, this is my first question in stackoverflow.

I want to convert RSS pubDate string(like this →　"`Tue, 28 Jul 2020 22:00:00 +0900`") to DateTime
in Flutter.

I spent 5 hours on this problem...please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dart, you can change it to the `DateTime` data using the `parse` method.

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse('2020-07-28 22:00:00.000');
```

**NOTE**

The `parse` method has its own input rules. Based on [the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) :

> The accepted inputs are currently:
>
> - A date: A signed four-to-six digit year, two digit month and two    digit day, optionally separated by - characters. Examples:
>   "19700101", "-0004-12-24", "81030-04-01".
> - An optional time part, separated from the date by either T or a    space. The time part is a two digit hour, then optionally a two digit
>   minutes value, then optionally a two digit seconds value, and then
>   optionally a '.' or ',' followed by at least a one digit second
>   fraction. The minutes and seconds may be separated from the previous
>   parts by a ':'. Examples: "12", "12:30:24.124", "12:30:24,124",
>   "123010.50".
> - An optional time-zone offset part, possibly separated from the    previous by a space. The time zone is either 'z' or 'Z', or it is a
>   signed two digit hour part and an optional two digit minute part. The
>   sign must be either "+" or "-", and can not be omitted. The minutes
>   may be separated from the hours by a ':'. Examples: "Z", "-10",
>   "+01:30", "+1130".

So you need to rearrange the input based on the rules above.

**Here's the examples of accepted String**

`2012-02-27 13:27:00`

`2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456789z`

`2012-02-27 13:27:00,123456789z`

`20120227 13:27:00`

`20120227T132700`

`20120227`

`+20120227`

`2012-02-27T14Z`

`2012-02-27T14+00:00`

`-123450101 00:00:00 Z`: in the year -12345.

`2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500`: Same as `2002-02-27T19:00:00Z`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! Hmm.. so I must make a new input string from pubDate to fit in accepted String. Is there any way to make new input?

Comment: Yes. And because I am really interested in this question, I've made a code to rearrange your string from `Tue, 28 Jul 2020 22:00:00 +0900` to `2020-07-28 22:00:00` and `parsed` it. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/hisamafahri/332d6b8d650baf372b7179c0051febfe

I assume my code will work fine because RSS PubDate has the rules on writing their DateTime syntax. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28

Comment: I have to give you a very big thank you..it becomes a big help for me.

Comment: It's my pleasure.