# Dart Function for Formatting Date and Time

Tags: string, flutter, dart

How do you create a function to convert something like `'11082020_150258'` to Date and time like `'11 August 2020'` and `'3:02 PM'` using Dart?

Answer (score 1):

You first will need to parse your string into a `DateTime` object.  Unfortunately, [`DateFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) from `package:intl` [does not support parsing timestamps without field separators](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/210), so you'll need to parse it manually.  You can use a regular expression:

```dart
var timestampString = '11082020_150258';
var re = RegExp(
  r'^'
  r'(?<day>\d{2})'
  r'(?<month>\d{2})'
  r'(?<year>\d{4})'
  r'_'
  r'(?<hour>\d{2})'
  r'(?<minute>\d{2})'
  r'(?<second>\d{2})'
  r'$',
);

var match = re.firstMatch(timestampString);
if (match == null) {
  throw FormatException('Unrecognized timestamp format');
}
var dateTime = DateTime(
  int.parse(match.namedGroup('year')),
  int.parse(match.namedGroup('month')),
  int.parse(match.namedGroup('day')),
  int.parse(match.namedGroup('hour')),
  int.parse(match.namedGroup('minute')),
  int.parse(match.namedGroup('second')),
);
```

Once you have a `DateTime` object, you can use `DateFormat` to format it:

```dart
var dateString = DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy').format(dateTime);
var timeString = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(dateTime);

print(dateString); // Prints: 11 August 2020
print(timeString); // Prints: 3:02 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a regex to parse the text:

```
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\d{2}");
```

The regex `\d{2}` matches every two digits of the string. Then you can make a list to store this group of digits:

```
Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches('11082020_150258');
var list = matches.map((m) => m.group(0)).toList();
```

Getting the date part of the string:

```
String dateStr = list.sublist(0, 3).join('/') + list[3].toString();
```

Getting the time part of the string:

```
String timeStr = list.sublist(4).join(':');
```

Creating a `DateTime` object from the string (using `DateFormat` from [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl))

```
var parsedDate = DateFormat('dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss').parse(dateStr + ' ' + timeStr);
```

You can use this `DateTime`. If you want to print it in the format mentioned in the question (i.e., `11 August 2020, 3:02 PM`):

```
DateFormat format = new DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy, HH:mm a', 'en_US');
print(format.format(parsedDate));
```

Full code:

```
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\d{2}");
Iterable<Match> matches =
exp.allMatches('11082020_150258');
var list =
matches.map((m) => m.group(0)).toList();
String dateStr =
    list.sublist(0, 3).join('/') + list[3].toString();
String timeStr = list.sublist(4).join(':');
var parsedDate = DateFormat('dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
    .parse(dateStr + ' ' + timeStr);
DateFormat format =
new DateFormat('d MMMM yyyy, HH:mm a', 'en_US');
print(format.format(parsedDate));
```