# Using DateFormat with locale causes FormatException: Trying to read yyyy from 2020-08-07 15:00 at position 0

Tags: android, ios, date, datetime, dart

I'm enable to do use `DateFormat` in flutter when am using the locale as `'ar'` which is `RTL` locale .. here is my code :

```dart
String finalDatetime = '$dateString $timeString';
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(finalDatetime);
String formattedDate = Intl.getCurrentLocale() == 'en' ? DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy – hh:mm').format(tempDate)
:DateFormat.yMMMd('ar').format(tempDate);
```

I'm getting the error in this line :

```dart
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(finalDatetime);
```

**The error**

```dart
FormatException: Trying to read yyyy from 2020-08-07 15:00 at position 0
```

**NOTES**

- It works perfectly when the locale is set to `'en'`
- The date string is being fetched from a database which is always sent as `2020-08-07 15:00`

Comment: You probably should [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues).  As a workaround, since the fetched string is always in a fixed format, you could use [`Intl.withLocale`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/Intl/withLocale.html) to force parsing with the `'en'` locale (or [manually parse it with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/)).

Comment: The only one working solution for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570895/flutter-locale-date-string-to-datetime/71599205#71599205

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as `Jamesdlin` mentioned on his comment, using `Intl.withLocale` fixed the problem

```dart
DateTime tempDate =Intl.withLocale('en', () => new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(finalDatetime));
```