# Flutter Locale Date String to DateTime

Tags: flutter, date, datetime, dart, flutter-layout

I want to convert date String* to DateTime object.

- String contains  month name in Turkish language like below

My String (from API) - `”10 Mart 2021 16:38”`

My Locale - Turkey [‘tr’]

How can I convert?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Only the en_US locale does not require any initialization. Other locales have to be initialized. For more info visit https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

// Then somewhere in your code:
initializeDateFormatting('tr_TR', null).then((_) {
      final dateAsString = '10 Mart 2021 16:38';
      final format = new DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm', 'tr_TR');
      final date = format.parse(dateAsString);
});
```

Comment: It Works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Jiffy](https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy) package, it also supports Turkish local since it runs on top of Inlt, making it easier to work with date and time

Set your locale to a Turkish locale

```
await Jiffy.setLocale("tr");
```

Then parse your string date time to `Jiffy`

```
DateTime dateTime = Jiffy.parse("10 Mart 2021 16:38", pattern: "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm").dateTime; // 2021-03-10 16:38:00.000
```

or simply

```
Jiffy.setLocale("tr").then((value) {
    DateTime dateTime = Jiffy.parse("10 Mart 2021 16:38", "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm").dateTime;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Spending a log of time trying to fix this issue, I've found one working solution:

1. Need to `parse` the date string ONLY with English locale:

   ```
    final dateTime = Intl.withLocale('en_US', () {
        const stringExample = 'Wed, 23 Mar 2022 13:48:05';
        const format = 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss';
        return DateFormat(format).parse(stringExample);
    });
   ```
2. Localise your date:

   ```
    initializeDateFormatting('tr', null).then((_) {
        final localisedDate = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(dateTime);
    });
   ```

You can `format` your date in step 2 directly without `initializeDateFormatting` method, if desired locale is set for `MaterialApp`