# time format of "Oct 20, 2020 7:47:31 PM" to datetime in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

all

In flutter dart,

I need chage "Oct 20, 2020 7:47:31 PM" to datetime,

what is time format of "Oct 20, 2020 7:47:31 PM".

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Comment: Thanks jamesdlin, My string is "Oct 20, 2020 7:47:31 PM",can not use DateTime.parse.

Comment: Did you read the other answers to that question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this *DateFormat*:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a');
```

Comment: Thanks dangngocduc,This a error:Trying to read MMM from Oct 24, 2020 12:43:54 PM at position 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/intl

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a')
              .format(DateTime.parse(DateTime.now().toString())))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thasks Reign,I used: DateTime dt=DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a').parse(oldtime);  but error:Trying to read MMM from Oct 24, 2020 12:43:54 PM at position 0. how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
var finalDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
```

Comment: if u want to make it in different read this : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: Thanks Nervous,has a error: DateTime dt=DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss a').parse(oldtime);