# Convert String into Date?

Tags: flutter, dart, date-conversion

I am getting date in String and I want to convert it into given Date format. Can anyone please guide me how can I do it ?

```
String myDate = 'June-2020'
```

I am getting date like this and I want to convert it into this `2020-06-01` format. `01` is default for every month.

```
var convertedDate = '2020-06-01'
```

Comment: did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart ? .. it has multiple answers that may answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom date format using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install) package

```
  String dateString1 = 'June-2020';
  String dateString2 = 'May-2021';

  DateFormat dateFormate = DateFormat('MMMM-yyyy');
  DateTime date1 = dateFormate.parse(dateString1);
  DateTime date2 = dateFormate.parse(dateString2);

  print(date1); //2020-06-01 00:00:00.000
  print(date2); //2020-05-01 00:00:00.000
```