# How to Convert String Date to Date Time?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert String format `12/05/2020` to DateTime `2020-12-05 00:00:00.000`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package and then:

```dart
var string = '12/05/2020';
var date1 = DateFormat('dd/MM/YYYY').parse(string);
var date2 = DateFormat('YYYY-MM-dd').format(date1);
```

For single line code

```
var date1 = DateTime.parse(DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(string).toIso8601String());
```

**Result**

```
2020-05-12 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string date1 = "12/05/2020";

DateTime dateTime = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(date1);

print(dateTime); // 2020-12-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

DateTime class has a method parse you can try using that. Following is an example.

```
String strDt = "1974-03-20 00:00:00.000";
DateTime parseDt = DateTime.parse(strDt);
print(parseDt); // 1974-03-20 00:00:00.000
```

Or you can use the package [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) to convert it if you need more customization.

Comment: OP is not having date in that format.