# Finding time and date with Regular Expression (RegEx) in Dart language

Tags: regex, flutter, datetime, dart, string-formatting

I'm writing an application with Flutter. I read the times and dates from a source. The date and time format string sent by the resource is:

(Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute, Second)

```
07.04.2021 13:30:00
03.04.2021 11:30:00
04.04.2021 17:30:00
03.04.2021 17:30:00
```

I want to convert this date and time format to DateTime data type with  `DateTime.parse()` function. Here are some examples of what this function accepts as strings and what I need:

```
"2012-02-27 13:27:00"
"20120227 13:27:00"
"20120227T132700"
```

I have to convert the string type data coming to me from the source into one of these formats. But in Dart language I couldn't create the Regular Expression needed to do this and couldn't find it anywhere.

**I would be very grateful if anyeone could help me understand what I should do.**

Comment: Also see [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/)

Comment: Thank you, I was having trouble converting to ISO 8601 format actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to play a lot with the dates, you could use the [Jiffy package](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) to ease your development.

```
DateTime yourDatetime = Jiffy("07.04.2021 13:30:00", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss").dateTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DateFormat.parse` and `DateFormat.format` from `intl` package:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat/parse.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat/format.html

```dart
final date = DateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss").parse("07.04.2021 13:30:00");

DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```

`DateTime.parse` accepts only a subset of ISO 8601 formats: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I have to do is convert the string data I mentioned above to the type below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a piece a cake by using regular expressions:

```
var regExp = RegExp(r'(\d{4}-?\d\d-?\d\d(\s|T)\d\d:?\d\d:?\d\d)');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The RegEx statement you gived returned `false` for `hasMatch`.