# Rounding seconds of time with HH:MM:SS format to nearest minute

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

For Example: [Sunset-Sunrise.org](https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=Sahara) provides sunset/sunrise time with HH:MM:SS format.

Given a time such as 12:53:57, I want to round the seconds to 12:54:00. Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

A general technique for rounding is to add half of the unit you want to round to and then to truncate.  For example, if you want to round an integer to the nearest ten's digit, you can add 5 and discard the one's digit: `((x + 5) ~/ 10) * 10`.

The same technique works for times too.  You can first [parse the `HH:MM:SS` string into a `DateTime` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/).  Then, to round the `DateTime` to the nearest minute, you can add 30 seconds and copy all of the resulting fields except for the seconds (and subseconds):

```dart
DateTime roundToMinute(DateTime dateTime) {
  dateTime = dateTime.add(const Duration(seconds: 30));
  return (dateTime.isUtc ? DateTime.utc : DateTime.new)(
    dateTime.year,
    dateTime.month,
    dateTime.day,
    dateTime.hour,
    dateTime.minute,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_time_fromat packages

from the docs

```
final timeOffset = dateTime.subtract(Duration(hours: 6, minutes: 45));

// 7 hours
print(DateTimeFormat.relative(timeOffset));

// 6 hours
print(DateTimeFormat.relative(timeOffset, round: false));
```

[This is the URL](https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_format)