# Flutter: DateFormat.parse returning wrong time at midnight only on Desktop Win32

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to parse a string into a DateTime in flutter.
On android, iOS and Web the procedure works perfectly, but on windows it keeps returning, only at midnight, the wrong time.

```
DateFormat('HH:mm').parse('00:25');
```

returns `1970-01-01 01:25:00.000` on windows, but `1970-01-01 00:25:00.000` on any other OS, while any hour >= 1 returns the right value.

If I try using parseStrict method, the following happens

```
DateFormat('HH:mm').parseStrict('00:25');
```

returns `FormatException: Error parsing 00:25, invalid hour value: 0 in it with time zone offset 1:00:00.000000. Expected value between 1 and 1. Date parsed as 1970-01-01 01:25:00.000..`

Thanks in advance for any help

Edit: This DateTime is in local timezone, I'm not trying to parse a UTC time. I've noticed, though, that if I add the date, the DateTime seems to get parsed properly.
But I need only the time.
These values are the open hours for a shop.
I know that I SHOULD use TimeOfDay class, but I can't use it because it doesn't have the compareTo method, which I need for my case scenario.
Anyway, I've tried Android, iOS and Web and they all parse the time properly, the only one problematic is Windows

Comment: have you tried with parseUTC, it seems like it is because of time zones

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This DateTime is in local timezone, I'm not trying to parse a UTC time. I've noticed, though, that if I add the date, the DateTime seems to get parsed properly. 
But I need only the time.
These values are the open hours for a shop.
I know that I SHOULD use TimeOfDay class, but I can't use it because it doesn't have the compareTo method, which I need for my case scenario. Anyways, I've tried Android, iOS and Web and they all parse the time properly, the only one problematic is Windows

Comment: "I know that I SHOULD use TimeOfDay class, but I can't use it because it doesn't have the compareTo method" ... Typically things like `List.sort` take a comparison callback for types that don't implement `Comparable`.  If you can't use a callback, you could make your own class around `TimeOfDay` (whether via inheritance or composition) that implements `Comparable`.  Other alternatives are to [parse the time yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/) or to internally prepend some dummy date string before parsing. `DateFormat.parse` isn't really meant to parse just times.