# how to convert date data in flutter or dart to string

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

helo

i have input string format date.

```
final dateControllerJoin = TextEditingController(); // value '2021-01-01'
```

and i post data to backend , but format date in backend this -> 2021-01-01T17:00:00Z

how to convert dateControllerJoin ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49385438/2804581

Comment: not work bro hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this conversion

```
var serverTime = "2021-01-01";
var displayTime =
    DateFormat("yyyy-MM-d").parse(serverTime); // Convert string to time
final DateFormat displayFormater =
    DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'Z'"); // Give expected format to display
print(displayFormater.format(displayTime)); // Output 2021-01-21T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: I have the format '2020-01-01' how to change to 2021-01-01T17:00:00Z ?