# how to get only date from the TableCalendar

Tags: flutter, date

I want to get only selected date from tablecalender, but it gives me this output

```
2021-08-18 12:00:00.000Z
```

**here is tablecalender code**

```
  final dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MMMM-dd');
  DateTime _chosenDate = DateTime.now();
child: TableCalendar(  
              calendarController: _controller, 
              initialSelectedDay: _chosenDate,
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,  
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
              canEventMarkersOverflow: true,
              markersColor: Colors.white,
              weekdayStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900]),
            
              
              todayColor: Colors.white54,
              todayStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900], fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              selectedColor: Colors.blue[900],
              outsideWeekendStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900]),
              outsideStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900]),
              weekendStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900]),
              renderDaysOfWeek: false,),  
              onCalendarCreated: (date,event,_){                             
              },
              onDaySelected: (date, event,_) {                 
                setState(() {
                 _chosenDate = date;
                  print("_chosenDate");
                  print(_chosenDate);                  
                });               
              },            
            ));  
            
  }
```

i tried to use split method, but it is not accessible

please help how to get only date (`2021-08-18`) using tablecalender

Comment: Check this and update the date format string as you required `YYYY-MM-dd` https://stackoverflow.com/a/68482059/2804581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in print replace `_chosenDate` with `"${_chosenDate.toString().split(" ").first}"`