# How to convert a simple string to a DateTime object?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I am tring to convert a simple string into a date time but it is showing invalid exception. Here's the code :

```
void main() {
  String date = '12';
  date = DateTime.parse(date).toString();
  print(date);
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What kind of date do you expect to get for `12`? Maybe you should try something like `2022-01-13`.

Comment: format your date string in `yyyy-mm-dd` to parse it.

Comment: It's unclear what result you expect for your example, but in general, see [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/)

Answer (score 1):

Your date string is not valid.
Here is example of it:

```
String time = '2022-01-13';

DateTime parseDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(time); // to be date
var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseDate.toString()); // to be string

var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy'); // set format be for ex 13 Jan 2022
var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate); // set to be a string
```

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't make much sense in this form, it will work:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  String date = '12';
  DateTime dateTime = DateFormat("MM").parse(date);
  print(dateTime);
}
```