# How to filter items consisting within a Date Range (from dateA to dateB) in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, filter, mobile-application

I am trying to create a filter where I need to filter using a range of Dates.

for eg. from  `2021-05-21` to `2021-08-31` .
I got `dateA` = `2021-05-21`, `dateB` = `2021-08-31`.

Suppose I have a list of Dates and list of Items below respectively:

the format of Date is `yyyy-mm-dd`.

`datesList` =

```
[ "2021-05-07", 
"2021-06-09", //
"2021-05-12", 
"2021-08-12", // 
"2021-04-15", 
"2021-07-08", // 
"2021-05-02",
"2021-06-31", // 
"2021-08-18", // 
"2021-02-09" ]
```

`itemsList` =

```
[ "Apple", 
"Mango",        // 
"Apple", 
"Pineapple,     // 
"Cinnamon", 
"Apple",        // 
"Mango",
"Banana",       // 
"Orange",       // 
"Orange" ]
```

Note: Here, for the 1st element in `datesList` for eg. `"2021-05-07"`, the respective item is the 1st item in `itemsList` which is `"Apple"`. i.e. both are having same indices, and both the lists are having same number of elements as well.

**How to find only the items in a particular date range?**

Let's say I need to filter from `2021-05-21` to `2021-08-31`.

Then I should get only `itemList[2]`, `itemList[4]`, `itemList[6]`, `itemList[8]`, `itemList[9]` from the `itemsList` as Output.
which is basically `["Mango", "Pineapple", "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]`

As only these items are present within this date range are needed to be filtered. (`dateA` = `2021-05-21`, `dateB` = `2021-08-31`.)

I couldn't even start as I am new in Flutter/Dart.

Kindly suggest me to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/) for how to parse your date strings into `DateTime` objects.  With that, you can iterate over you lists, compare each parsed `DateTime` against your start and end dates, and then add the corresponding item to list of results.

For example:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

/// Returns a list of items that have corresponding dates between [start]
/// and [end] (inclusive).
List<String> itemsBetweenDates({
  required List<String> dates,
  required List<String> items,
  required DateTime start,
  required DateTime end,
}) {
  assert(dates.length == items.length);

  var dateFormat = DateFormat('y-MM-dd');

  var output = <String>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i += 1) {
    var date = dateFormat.parse(dates[i], true);
    if (date.compareTo(start) >= 0 && date.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
      output.add(items[i]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}

void main() {
  var startDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 05, 21);
  var endDate = DateTime.utc(2021, 08, 31);

  var datesList = [
    "2021-05-07",
    "2021-06-09", //
    "2021-05-12",
    "2021-08-12", //
    "2021-04-15",
    "2021-07-08", //
    "2021-05-02",
    "2021-06-31", //
    "2021-08-18", //
    "2021-02-09",
  ];

  var itemsList = [
    "Apple",
    "Mango", //
    "Apple",
    "Pineapple", //
    "Cinnamon",
    "Apple", //
    "Mango",
    "Banana", //
    "Orange", //
    "Orange",
  ];

  print(itemsBetweenDates(
      dates: datesList, items: itemsList, start: startDate, end: endDate));
}
```

Note that the above assumes that the start and end dates are *inclusive*.  If you want, say, the end date to be exclusive, change `date.compareTo(end) <= 0` to `date.compareTo(end) < 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped. :) #LifeSaver.