# Dart DateFormat inconsistency

Tags: flutter, dart, date-format, flutter-intl, dart-intl

I'm trying to parse date string that looks like this `Feb0920221500` (month, day in month, year, hours, minutes). But when I use `MMMddyyyyHmm` pattern I always get a `FormatException`. Furthermore `intl`'s `DateFormat` fails to parse back a date which it has formatted before:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final dateFormat = DateFormat("MMMddyyyyHmm");
  final dateString = dateFormat.format(DateTime.now());
  print(dateString);
  final date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
  print(date);
}
```

Output:

```
Feb0920221511
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Trying to read yyyy from Feb0920221511 at position 13
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is definitely strange.. Try filing an issue here (or see if there's one already): https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues

Comment: There is an issue already – it is https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/210 / Seems like both methods are not really designed to work fully reversible.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into this issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/210

TL/DR: Both methods are not designed to work fully reversible, if I understood the package maintainers correctly.

Try to introduce field separators like a space or a dot as a workaround:

```dart
  final dateFormat = DateFormat("MMM dd yyyy H mm");
  final dateString = dateFormat.format(DateTime.now());
  print(dateString);
  print(dateFormat.parseStdaterict(dateString));
```

If the format of the given date String cannot be changed, you still have the possibility to make it work with a hack like this. Just make sure to handle errors gracefully.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final parsedDate = 'Feb0920221511'.parseToDate();
  print(parsedDate.toIso8601String());
}

extension CustomDateParser on String {
  DateTime parseToDate() {
    try {
      final month = substring(0, 3);
      final day = substring(3, 5);
      final year = substring(5, 9);
      final hour = substring(9, 11);
      final minute = substring(11, 13);

      final paddedDateString = '$month $day $year $hour $minute';
      final dateFormat = DateFormat('MMM dd yyyy H mm');
      return dateFormat.parse(paddedDateString);
    } catch (e) {
      // handle error
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Given that I cannot change format of string coming from somewhere else what would you recommend to parse it without separators?

Comment: If the format never changes, I would write a small fixed length parser for the date. You could implement that as an extension to String or DateTime for example. It doesn't matter much.

Comment: I added a small workaround, which might help you with this issue. Just be aware, that DateFormat is locale aware. You should probably use a fixed locale with it in this case.