# How to trasfer a List<String> values to a DateTime<List> datetime values?? Flutter/Dart

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart, datetime

I have a List with some string values inside (undefined number of how many but they are dates) i want to convert these values to DateTime and then to store each one to this line:

```
specialDates:[DateTime(2022, 08, 16),DateTime(2022,08,03)]),
```

this line only accept DateTime values

Comment: Add the date string in the question.

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: Which string list model do you want to convert to date list, I need this string list to understand what to do.

Comment: See [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/), but do it in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that list have right strings, which could be converted into DateTime, you should follow this snip:

```
 specialDates = stringsL.map((element) => DateTime.parse(element)).toList();
```

Comment: yes you are right, how can i display a spesific index-element from this list now?

Comment: To display elemnt by index in a list, for expamle, in a text widget, you should write like this: `Text(specialDates[i])`, wheres i - integer number, which means position in your list, in a range between 0 (start) and specialDates.length-1 (last element index in list)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by `DateTime<List>` you mean `List<DateTime>`. In this case, you can combine `List.map` with `DateTime.parse` to quickly convert the entire string list into a list of `Datetime` objects.

```dart
final strings = [
  '2022-01-01T12:00:00Z',
  '2022-01-02T12:00:00Z',
  '2022-01-03T12:00:00Z',
  '2022-01-04T12:00:00Z',
];

final dates = strings.map((s) => DateTime.parse(s)).toList();
```

If you wanted to be concise, you could reference `DateTime.parse` directly so as to eliminate the lambda function entirely:

```dart
final dates = strings.map(DateTime.parse).toList();
```

Note that this assumes that all of the strings in the list are valid date-time strings in a format that `DateTime.parse` can recognize (such as an [ISO-8601 timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). If you can't guarantee that will always be the case, instead of `DateTime.parse`, you want to use `DateTime.tryParse`. However, `tryParse` will return a `DateTime?` instead of a `DateTime` (meaning it can be null), so if you don't want that, you will need to do a bit more work on the list to filter out the nulls:

```dart
final strings = [
  '2022-01-01T12:00:00Z',
  '2022-01-02T12:00:00Z',
  '2022-01-03T12:00:00Z',
  'asdfasd',
  '2022-01-04T12:00:00Z',
];

// Results in a List<DateTime?> with bad strings becoming null
final dates = strings.map(DateTime.tryParse).toList();

// Results in a List<DateTime> with bad strings filtered out
final dates = strings.map(DateTime.tryParse)
                     .where((dt) => dt != null)
                     .cast<DateTime>()
                     .toList();
```