# Dynamically Calculate Time using Loops in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create 96 Map objects in a List with the following `key-value` pairs

```
{
    'id': 1, 
    'time': '00:00-00:15', 
    'slotNumber': '01', 
    'clicked': false
}
```

Although this is something that is easily achievable using loops, the main complication starts when it comes to generating the time range. The `time` key in every object needs to be at an interval of 15 minutes each and should be in a 24-hour format. For example, the next few time ranges need to be `00:15-00:30`, `00:30-00:45`, `00:45-01:00`, and so on. I tried hard to look for a package that would answer all my prayers but couldn't find any.

The final output needs to look something like this:

```
var kSlots = [
  {'id': 1, 'time': '00:00-00:15', 'slotNumber': '01', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 2, 'time': '00:15-00:30', 'slotNumber': '02', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 3, 'time': '00:45-01:00', 'slotNumber': '03', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 4, 'time': '01:00-01:15', 'slotNumber': '04', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 5, 'time': '01:15-01:30', 'slotNumber': '05', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 6, 'time': '01:30-01:45', 'slotNumber': '06', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 7, 'time': '01:45-02:00', 'slotNumber': '07', 'clicked': false},
  {'id': 8, 'time': '02:00-02:15', 'slotNumber': '08', 'clicked': false}]
```

As I now need to generate the time from a given start date which is in String, I tried modifying @jamesdlin 's answer a bit to achieve that. But it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Invalid date format
08:00

String getTimeRange(int i) {
  var midnight = DateTime.parse(DateFormat('HH:mm').format(DateTime.parse('08:00')));
  const interval = Duration(minutes: 15);
  var start = midnight.add(interval * i);
  var end = start.add(interval);
  var formatTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format;
  return '${formatTime(start)}-${formatTime(end)}';
  
}

void main() {
  var slots = [
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 1)
    <String, dynamic>{
      'id': i + 1,
      'time': getTimeRange(i),
      'slotNumber': '${i + 1}'.padLeft(2, '0'),
      'clicked': false,
    },
  ];
  
  slots.forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: Just construct a `DateTime` object directly with the time you want: `DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 8)`.  Also don't name that variable `midnight`.

Comment: And what if the time was in HH:mm format? How would you suggest I used something like 08:45 in place of 8?

Comment: If the time is known, then you can still use the `DateTime` constructor (`DateTime(2022, 1, 1, 8, 45)`).  If you need to parse a string dynamically, then you would need to use `DateFormat('HH:mm').parse`, not `DateTime.parse`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over an index and use the index as a multiplier for a `Duration` of 15 minutes.

You then either can add that multiplied `Duration` to a `DateTime` representing midnight (if your time ranges represent points in time) or format those `Duration`s directly (if they represent durations).

I assuming that your times represent points in time:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String getTimeRange(int i) {
  var midnight = DateTime.utc(2022, 1, 1);
  const interval = Duration(minutes: 15);
  var start = midnight.add(interval * i);
  var end = start.add(interval);
  var formatTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format;
  return '${formatTime(start)}-${formatTime(end)}';
  
}

void main() {
  var slots = [
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i += 1)
    <String, dynamic>{
      'id': i + 1,
      'time': getTimeRange(i),
      'slotNumber': '${i + 1}'.padLeft(2, '0'),
      'clicked': false,
    },
  ];
  
  slots.forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: What do I need to change to start calculating from a particular time? Like let's say If I wanted to start generating the time slots from 08:00?

Comment: @coolhack7 Then use 08:00 as the base time instead of midnight.

Comment: I have kind of tried that but it didn't work which probably is due to me going wrong somewhere. I have therefore updated the question with what I have done above. Do you think you can go through it once and point out what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set use the `DateTime` class instead of String and manipulate it as you desire: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html