# How can i convert a DateTime variable "2022-09-29T07:26:52.000Z" to seconds in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable in dart string and would like to convert it all to seconds or minutes....

```
String x = "2022-09-29T07:26:52.000Z"
```

I want the opposite of this code below

```
final newYearsDay =
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1640979000000, isUtc:true);
print(newYearsDay); // 2022-01-01 10:00:00.000Z
```

I want to be able to get this back to seconds from the current timedate formart

Comment: Do you mean convert to dateTime ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just want to get the equivalent in hours or minutes or seconds...

Comment: what will be the  current string output?

Comment: @Flochristos What does that mean?  If you want the number of seconds since the Unix "epoch", see [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49385303/) to get a `DateTime` object, and then you can use `dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000`.  If that's not what you want, then provide an *example* of what you do want.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh something like "37684904983040504" seconds

Comment: @jamesdlin i want the exact opposite of what you just said.. ```final newYearsDay =
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1640979000000, isUtc:true);
print(newYearsDay); // 2022-01-01 10:00:00.000Z``` Opposite of this, to turn back the datetime to seconds

Comment: How you've reached to `37684904983040504` seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your string to a `datetime` by using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) like this:

```
String x = "2022-09-29T07:26:52.000Z";
var dateTime = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss').parse(x);
```

and for get the number of milliseconds since the `Unix epoch` :

```
print("numbers= ${dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch}")
```

Comment: Not really, here, you only got the individual time in it, what i want is to get all of that into a single value which is seconds or minutes... or hours...

Comment: check out last part of my updated answer @Flochristos

Comment: that is exactly opposite of what you added to question

Comment: Okay, lemme check...brb

Comment: It is...... Thanks so much... i was able to get the precise answer with ```var ttt = (dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000);```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` has a `parse` static that can parse many (but not all) date formats. The ISO8601 format is one that it can parse - including the trailing Z.

```
void main() {
  final dt1 = DateTime.parse('2022-09-29T07:26:52.000Z');

  print(dt1.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000);
}
```