Dart DateFormat problem, states can not read MM at position 8
I am trying to parse a date string that comes in on a string log entry.
The string is 20240716 154138
I am using this code and can not find why it is failing.
String timestampStr = '20240716 154138';
final timestamp = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd HHmmss').parse(timestampStr!)

I get this error:
FormatException: Trying to read MM from 20240716 154138 at 8
I have tried single M and lowercase mm and still gives me the error. I am testing in Dartpad to see if I can clear the error.
Any  help is appreciated

DateFormat cannot parse dates that lack explicit field separators.  Try using FixedDateTimeFormatter instead from package:convert.

@jamesdlin do you have any example of using it, can not seem to get it to recognize even after the import.  Any example would help.  Thanks

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61394854/.  For your case, FixedDateTimeFormatter('YYYYMMDD hhmmss').decode(timestampStr) should work.

Thanks to @jamesdin I ended up just parsing the date first then create the datatime since intl does not support without separaters.
  int? year = int.parse(timestampStr!.substring(0, 4));
  int? month = int.parse(timestampStr.substring(4, 6));
  int? day = int.parse(timestampStr.substring(6, 8));
  int? hour = int.parse(timestampStr.substring(9, 11));
  int? minute = int.parse(timestampStr.substring(11, 13));
  int? second = int.parse(timestampStr.substring(13, 15));

  // Creating DateTime object
  DateTime timestamp = DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

