# changing date formatter's locale

Tags: dart, flutter

am using Date formatter in my app to display some dates.. but i want this date to be shown in Arabic .. so i tried to change locale of the formatter like this this:

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var formatter = DateFormat.yMMMd("ar_SA");
String formatted = formatter.format(now);
print(formatted);
```

but its not working ..

if i changed it to this:

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var formatter = DateFormat.yMMMd("en_US");
String formatted = formatter.format(now);
print(formatted);
```

Will work fine .. but i want the date to be displayed in Arabic ..

how to achieve this? i want the date to be for example ١١ يناير ٢٠١٨.. how to do it?

Comment: What does "but its not working .." mean exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `initializeDateFormatting` to get the correct date formatter like this:

```
initializeDateFormatting("ar_SA", null).then((_) {
      var now = DateTime.now();
      var formatter = DateFormat.yMMMd('ar_SA');
      print(formatter.locale);
      String formatted = formatter.format(now);
      print(formatted);
    });
```

or with async-await you could do:

```
await initializeDateFormatting("ar_SA", null);
var now = DateTime.now();
var formatter = DateFormat.yMMMd('ar_SA');
print(formatter.locale);
String formatted = formatter.format(now);
print(formatted);
```

This results in the following output for me:

```
ar
١٢ نوفمبر ٢٠١٨
```

Comment: @lamatat if you find the answer useful, please upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

and just make sure import  data local

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
```