# Dart - How to change format of simple date string which is in yyyy-MM-dd to dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a srting date 2019-09-30, I want to convert it to 30-09-2019 in dart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)

Comment: Hey Shashank, check out the link above! I guess it could solve your problem better using the intl package with proper functions for date formatting. Good luck :)

Comment: @George well I have seen the above answer before asking. The answers given above only formats DateTime.now() but I want to format a string thats' why I asked it here. Fatima 's answer used DateTime.parse to convert string to DateTime that helped me

Comment: Alright, no prob :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use intl.dart to formate any date .
Here is a simple example of this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String dateFormate;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dateFormate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.parse("2019-09-30"));
    return Container(
      child: Text(dateFormate),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add `intl: ^0.16.0` to your `pubspec.yaml` to use it

Comment: How to convert dd-MM-YYYY string format date in date object?

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [**intl**](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

This package has a great class called [**DateFormat**](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) that can easily do it for you .

**Installing :**
Add this to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
 intl: any
```

**Usage :**
Just pass your date  to `DateFormat("date pattern").format(date)`

**Example**

```
DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateTime.parse("2019-09-30"));
```

Output : `30-09-2019`

**Another Example**

```
print(DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.now()));
```

Output : `2/7/2021`

[This package](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) includes many other tools . You can learn more about them [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/).