# Change format DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I can change format when I assign "selectedDate" to "dateBirthdayUser"? I need that "dateBirthdayUser" show date like that '31/12/2019". Thx

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  DateTime dateBirthdayUser = DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        },
        locale: Locale('es'),
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1950, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;        
        dateBirthdayUser = selectedDate;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126580/11320875)

You need to use DateFormat class

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

And use it for different formats

[Check official docs to date format class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)