# Datetime without 00:00:00.000 for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why everytime I make a

```
var date = DateTime.parse(dob);
var formattedDate = '${date.year}${date.month}${date.day}';  
DateTime.parse(formattedDate)
```

it will still retrieve as `1961-02-26 00:00:00.000`? How do I get it to become `19610226` but still in datatype DateTime?

Answer (score 2):

Use DateFormat Class from intl package to format your date

```
var date = DateTime.parse(dob);
var dateFormatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
String formattedDate = dateFormatter.format(date);
print(formattedDate); // result 2020-03-24
```

for more details and more formatting options see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126580/8567899)

Comment: but then it is in String datatype, i want it to be DateTime

Comment: DateTime.parse() should do your bidding.