# Format the date with day and month

Tags: date, flutter, datepicker, format

How would I format the date returned to be displayed with the day and month eg 23 AUG with my code.

```
 var finaldate;

  void callDatePicker() async {
    var order = await getDate();
    setState(() {
      finaldate = order;
    });
  }

  Future<DateTime> getDate() {
    return showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
```

```
Text('$finaldate',
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateFormat` from the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

```dart
DateFormat('dd MMM, yyyy').format(finaldate) // gives 27 Jun, 2020
```