# GMT time String to DateTime in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert string to `DateTime` in dart. I tried,

```
String timeVal = "Thu, 25 Mar 2021 19:29:28 GMT";
DateTime.parse(timeVal);
```

but getting an exception,

> FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format Thu, 25 Mar 2021
> 19:29:28 GMT)

How could I convert such a string value to `DateTime` in dart

Comment: You'll probably need the DateFormat.parse() from the 'intl' package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert datetime string to datetime object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/convert-datetime-string-to-datetime-object-in-dart) `HttpDate.parse` should be able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final string = 'Thu, 25 Mar 2021 19:29:28 GMT';
  final formatter = DateFormat('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss');
  final dateTime = formatter.parse(string);
  print(dateTime); // prints : 2021-03-25 19:29:28.000
}
```

For more info, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126580/10976714) and the [DartFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class docs.

Please note, the parsed `DateTime` in the example does not have the correct time zone (ie `dateTime.timeZoneName` will return your local time zone).