# Changing Date and time Time formate from Json Response in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friend I am new in dart fetching data from Api  now I want format this date time. In this way => Mar 20, 2021 11:36 am.. While json response coming this way =>":"2021-03-20 11:36:00

Here is my json full response file please check answer the question?

```
"message":"Data fetched successfully",
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "public_id":"ed0042ca-5a14-476b-9b65-66461efa81ae",
         "title":"LIVE CONCERT",
         "image":"https:\/\/livinghopemobile.com\/public\/storage\/event\/200321_113705_image.png",
         "datetime":"2021-03-20 11:36:00",  <=
         "description":"LIVE CONCERT",
         "created_at":"2021-03-20T06:37:05.000000Z",
         "updated_at":"2021-03-29T07:18:50.000000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String date = DateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a").format(DateTime.parse("2021-03-20 11:36:00"));
 print(date); // =>Mar 20, 2021 11:36 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
 var date = "2021-03-24T08:57:47.812" 
 var dateTime =  DateTime.parse("$date");
 var stdTime =  DateFormat('MMM d, yy hh:mm a').format(dateTime).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var time = DateTime.parse(data[0]['datetime']);
```

And then you can look up here on the dates format list [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)

```
var myTime =  DateFormat('MMM d, yy hh:mm a').format(time);
```