# How to correctly convert a String to DateTime?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a String that looks exactly like this: "12/12/2000" and I have tried to convert it into DateTime but I couldn't get what I wish it was. I want my DateTime to looks exactly like the String value. I am using Flutter. The code below is how I am trying to convert it but It doesn't show the exactly value of string:

```
String date = "12/12/2000";
String dateConvert = date.substring(0, 8);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateConvert);
print(dateTime);
```

Comment: Your question is very vague. A recommendation, try using Simple Date formatter.

Comment: I am using Dart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)

Comment: @Tess2552 That question is about formatting (`DateTime` to `String`).  This question is about parsing (`String` to `DateTime`).

Comment: [How do I convert a date/time string to a DateTime object in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385303/how-do-i-convert-a-date-time-string-to-a-datetime-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 2):

I made it just like this:

```
DateTime convertedDate = new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse("12/12/2000");
print(convertedDate);
```

Thank you everyone who dedicated time to answer. I hope I can help some other people!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat. Look these examples:

```
String sDate1="31/12/1998";  
String sDate2 = "31-Dec-1998";  
String sDate3 = "12 31, 1998";  
String sDate4 = "Thu, Dec 31 1998";  
String sDate5 = "Thu, Dec 31 1998 23:37:50";  
String sDate6 = "31-Dec-1998 23:37:50";  
SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
SimpleDateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");  
SimpleDateFormat formatter3=new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy");  
SimpleDateFormat formatter4=new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy");  
SimpleDateFormat formatter5=new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
Date date1=formatter1.parse(sDate1);  
Date date2=formatter2.parse(sDate2);  
Date date3=formatter3.parse(sDate3);  
Date date4=formatter4.parse(sDate4);  
Date date5=formatter5.parse(sDate5);  
Date date6=formatter6.parse(sDate6);
```

For this you will need import:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;
```

Comment: This is not for flutter.

Comment: Yes, the solution is for Java. It remained to specify, because Java was placed in the Tag.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.parse does not accept the given format, the acceptable formats are described in the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.2/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html).

Using the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, you can do the following:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String date = "12/12/2000";
DateTime dateTime = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
print(dateTime);
```

To use the package, you have to add the dependency to your pubspec.yaml file.

I would personally recommend using the [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead, which is accepted by DateTime.parse.