# How can I change time format in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetime

I want to change time 02:21:22  into 2 hours 21 minutes 22 seconds. How can I do this in flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a string you can use split method using delimeter : and then appending hours minutes and seconds to the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html) method to achieve this.

```
 final String time = '02:21:22';
 final List<String> durations = time.split(':');

  print('${durations[0]} hours ${durations[1]} minutes ${durations[2]} seconds');
  // Prints 02 hours 21 minutes 22 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
var formatTime  = myTime.replaceFirst(':',' Hours ').replaceFirst(':',' Minutes ') + ' Seconds';
print(formatTime); //02 Hours 21 Minutes 22 Seconds
```