# Flutter - date format for print date like MMMdy

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need to display date like 22 Dec 2021. How could I achieve this?
`DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date)`
this gives date like Dec 22, 2021.

Comment: Does [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126580/4168607) works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, first import `package:intl/intl.dart` then :

```dart
 DateTime now = DateTime.now();
 String formatted = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(now);
 print(formatted); // prints 22 Dec 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package for this.
Date formatting works using skeletons. In this case what we need is dd, MM and yyyy skeleton.

```dart
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy');
  print(formatter.format(date));
```

Let's say you want 22/Dec/2021 for any reason, you can just paas `dd/MMM/yyyy` to DateFormat and the date will be returned as needed. You can get a list of all skeletons [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html). The `yMMMd` function you have used here uses skeletons under the hood. These are just some of the more common ones.