# Date Picker in flutter without time

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

I am trying to pick a date only. I used [`flutter_holo_date_picker`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_holo_date_picker) dependency. When I select date I get time with it. But I only want date not time. How can I remove it?

Here is my code -

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_holo_date_picker/flutter_holo_date_picker.dart';

class WidgetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetPageState createState() => _WidgetPageState();
}

class _WidgetPageState extends State<WidgetPage> {
  late DateTime _selectedDate;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
            child: Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: DatePickerWidget(
                      looping: false, // default is not looping
                      firstDate: DateTime(1990, 01, 01),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2030, 1, 1),
                      initialDate: DateTime(1991, 10, 12),
                      dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                      locale: DatePicker.localeFromString('en'),
                      onChange: (DateTime newDate, _) =>
                          _selectedDate = newDate,
                      pickerTheme: const DateTimePickerTheme(
                        itemTextStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19),
                        dividerColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        print('current_date: $_selectedDate');
                      },
                      child: const Text('submit'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output -
[image: 1]

Expected output will be -

> current_date: 2022-1-1

Comment: check this link : https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-datepicker-in-flutter-37e84f7d8d6c

Answer (score 0):

`DatePickerWidget`'s `onChange` method provide [`DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/dart-core/DateTime-class.html).
You can format this date with `DateFormat` from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

```dart
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
final String output = formatter.format(_selectedDate);
```

I will encourage you to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126580/10157127).