# Flutter/Dart : Parsing 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS' producing wrong output?

Tags: flutter, date, dart, datetime

I am parsing a date in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS` using DateFormat

But I am getting some other date in parsed output

```
final dt = '2022-02-07 05:00:11';
final datm =  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS').parse(dt);

print ("DATE_CALC ${datm.day} - ${datm.month} - ${datm.year} ${datm.hour} : ${datm.minute} : ${datm.second}   ");
```

**Actual Output:**

```
DATE_CALC 7 - 2 - 2021 5 : 0 : 0
```

**Expected :**

```
DATE_CALC 07 - 12 - 2022 05 : 00 : 11
```

Why I am getting some wrong date ? Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MM  is not month and minutes....  mm or MM  :-)

```
wrong 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS'
correct 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

Comment: Yeah got it :  7 - 2 - 2022 5 : 0 : 11 . Thanks .

Comment: One help. Is it possible to print with leading zeros like this 07 - 02 - 2022 5 : 00 : 11 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
final dt = '2022-02-07 05:00:11';
final datm =  DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dt);
  print ("DATE_CALC ${datm.day} - ${datm.month} - ${datm.year} ${datm.hour} : ${datm.minute} : ${datm.second}   ");
```

Try this
Hour minute and seconds can be parsed like this `HH:mm:ss` not like `HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Working . Thanks . One help. Is it possible to print with leading zeros like this 07 - 02 - 2022 5 : 00 : 11 ?

Comment: print ("DATE_CALC ${datm.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}"); try this

It will print `DATE_CALC 07`

Answer (score 1):

Your formate is wrong

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS` replace to `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`

Comment: Working . Thanks . One help. Is it possible to print with leading zeros like this 07 - 02 - 2022 5 : 00 : 11 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart

Answer (score 1):

it should be `final datm =  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').parse(dt);`

Comment: Working . Thanks . One help. Is it possible to print with leading zeros like this 07 - 02 - 2022 5 : 00 : 11 ?

Comment: you can try this :    print ("DATE_CALC ${datm.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} - ${datm.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} - ${datm.year} ${datm.hour} : ${datm.minute} : ${datm.second}   ");